# How can I restore the swap drive used by ubuntu, back to windows 7?

Tags: windows, swap, drive, partitioning

I just installed ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop (which has windows 7) but I used my second data drive as a swap for Ubuntu. How can I restore this swap drive back so it can be accessed  by Windows 7 again?

(Everything else works normally as a dual boot system there is no problem).

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/26512/sharing-swap-space-between-windows-and-ubuntu

Comment: @ubfan1 The OP don't want to *share* the partition, but him want to *use it*. That means, delete -> resize -> format it.

Answer (score 0):

Just start "gparted" in Ubuntu and "format" the swap-partition to ntfs... ;)

BE CAREFUL! Every data on the formated partition will be deleted!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you include a answer with instructions on how to do that? Leaving a [half-answer as a comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments) can often cause more harm than good. Thanks!