# How to disable cryptswap?

Tags: filesystem, security, encryption, swap

How can I disable cryptswap? I would like an unencrypted swap like before.

This is on an ubuntu 9.10 system.

Answer (score 15):

To remove crypt mapping use something like this:

`cryptsetup remove cryptswap1`

Or just reboot the computer. If you remove/comment lines from `/etc/crypttab` and `/etc/fstab`, encrypted swap will not created on the next boot.

Answer (score 11):

If you used cryptsetup to create your encrypted swap, you can easily reverse the process:

Currently your /dev/hda? will be mapped to cryptswap (something like cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/hda4 cryptswap)

so first disable the line in /etc/crypttab that mentions cryptswap and remove the cryptswap line from /etc/fstab

Then use cryptsetup to remove the crypt mapping.

At this point you can remove the swap partition and [recreate it as an ordinary partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/adding-swap-partition-after-system-installation/33703#33703)