# Why is this in my fstab /dev/mapper/cryptswap1?

Tags: 11.10, hibernate, swap, encrypted-partition

With my new Ubuntu 11.10, I have, I was not able to hibernate my system. When I checked if I have alloted enough swap space, I found the following lines in my fstab.

```
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
#UUID=69d389f9-f78e-4da8-b044-85faf53650ed none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

why is swap modified? i dont want any encryption for my swap. I want to be able to hibernate my laptop. How do I undo this?

Answer (score 4):

Already answered: [How to disable cryptswap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34519/how-to-disable-cryptswap)

Also that line is commented out, so it's not actually doing anything right now, you have no swap, if that's the only swap line.