# How to create launchers that open applications in a terminal?

Tags: unity, 11.10, launcher

I would like to make a launcher that directs an application to be opened in a terminal.

I had it on Maverick and it worked. And also, it added the application to the 'Installed applications'.

At this moment, on 11.10 I can only make the desktop launcher. If I move it to the Unity launcher, it creates a permanent launcher item, and it's not included in the 'Installed Apps' list as well.

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: How do these answers stand up for you? Also can you consider closing or accepting some of your other questions. It is always good to know which answers actually helped you for future visitors with the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Graphical method**
To create launchers that lets you open applications in terminal, you can try alacarte.

First of all, you need to have [alacarte](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/alacarte) [image: Install alacarte] installed.              After installing it, open alacarte. On the right side, there would be an option to create a *New item*. Click on it.

[image]

When you click the button, a dialog box of title *Create launcher* would appear. For the option *Type*, choose *Application in Terminal*. Give appropriate name to the launcher item and the actual command to execute and so on. After that, click *OK* and that would save the launcher item.

[image]

Now, search for the launcher in the dash and then pin it to your launcher. Clicking on the launcher item would now open the application in terminal.

[image]

*Note: There is a good chance that you might actually end up pinning the original launcher item which doesn't open in a terminal. So, good luck on pinning the correct launcher item.*

**Command-line method**

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/minitube.desktop
```

Here `/usr/share/applications/minitube.desktop` is an example I used. You can use the exact path to the file that you want to edit.

Change the line `Terminal=false` to `Terminal=true`. If there is no such line, then add one: `Terminal=true`.

- [How to edit files in a terminal with nano?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54221/how-to-edit-files-in-a-terminal-with-nano)

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried it, works perfect. Brilliant.

Comment: Pretty pr0 illustrated answer :) Thanks!

Comment: @Automat Since this answer works for you, consider accepting the answer - there is a checkmark shaped button to the left of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand, but I'll have a go anyway. If you mean you want to open a new terminal window and run a command in it, then that's easy. And if you've managed to create the .desktop-file, then you can just copy it to ~/-local/share/applications to make it available in the dash. You can then drag it to the launcher and keep it there if you want to.

Another solution that might be interesting to you, is to add the commands to the terminal quicklist. You can see an example of that here: [What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/39532#39532)