# How to change shortcut in pidgin?

Tags: shortcut-keys, pidgin

I use pidgin to chat... At the moment `Alt-S` launches `Smiles`, does anyone know how to change it to `send the message`?

Answer (score 4):

I tried my best but I failed at assigning <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>S</kbd> to send the messages. But, what I did manage to do is to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to send the message. Hope that is enough of a compromise.

Before you edit, please ensure that you have closed all the current instances of Pidgin.

```
cd .purple/
nano gtkrc-2.0
```

Paste the following content in it:

```
binding "my-bindings"
{    
    bind "<ctrl>s" { "message_send" () }
}
widget "*pidgin_conv_entry" binding "my-bindings"
```

After pasting it, save the file. If you are not sure how to use Nano, follow this question:

- [How to edit files in a terminal with nano?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54221/how-to-edit-files-in-a-terminal-with-nano)

Now, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> will send the messages in Pidgin.

Reference:

- [How do I make Enter make a newline and Ctrl+Enter send?](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#HowdoImakeEntermakeanewlineandCtrlEntersend)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks jokerdino.

I wanted to add a little bit for those like me bent on **Alt-S** to send.
I've loaded Pidgin 2.10.# in both Ubuntu 12 and Windows OSs, and the following works on both.

In Version 2.10 at least, you can go to the preferences -> conversations settings.
You will see an example toolbar for font settings and smileys, etc. This example is the default chat window toolbar arrangement for all chats.  You can change from grouped to ungrouped icons by right clicking on the example toolbar and selecting "ungroup."  This change will make the menu a little more unruly, but the change will also remove the smiley button that has alt-s hot-keyed to open smileys up.  From here, you can do the same coding in the gtk files as jokerdino submits, but instead use:

```
binding "my-bindings"
{   
    bind "<alt>s" { "message_send" () }  
}
widget "*pidgin_conv_entry" binding "my-bindings"
```

The combination will make it so you can do **Alt-S** to send.  I recommend using the  2nd reference link that jokerdino posts to also create a return/enter key-bind for CRLF.

BTW, for Win users, the gtk file is called *gtkrc* in the path you installed Pidgin:

> Pidgin\Gtk\share\themes\MS-Windows\gtk-2.0\

(for me)

Sorry for digging up a year old thread, but this shows at the top of the list, and I thought it was the best place to answer.  Plus, I've yet to submit something here since using Ubuntu!

Another link that eventually gets to the same conclusion that I found as I was typing this up: [Official Pidgin Enhancement Request](https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/10353)

Comment: This also works using a `gtkrc-2.0` file in the `.purple` directory.