# How to resolve the "GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition" error when using boot-repair?

Tags: boot-repair

After installing Ubuntu, Windows didn't boot so I installed boot repair to fix this problem. But I am getting the message displayed below.

I tried to make a new partition with unformatted file system but still receiving the same message.

How do I fix it?

[image: the screenshot]

Comment: You need to do as the message says and set the bios_grub flag.

Answer (score 2):

First you should check if booting the system as MBR/BIOS instead UEFI is really what you intended.

The following is a quote from [Is it still possible to install Ubuntu to an external harddrive with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/559007/40581) which is about several ways of setting up bootloaders and necessary partitions. Refer to the original answer if some of the instructions are unclear (it would have been very repetitive to explain almost the same thing in detail 3-4 times).

> Creating a **BIOS Bootable Partition** (BBP) for GRUB is a bit
>   different:
>
> 1. Install the `grub-pc-bin` package.
> 2. Create a partition similar to the instructions above by resizing the root partition and set the `bios_grub` flag. Choose **no
>      filesystem** and leave it unformatted.
> 3. Edit the configuration file `/etc/default/grub` with administrative rights and add `GRUB_DEVICE=/dev/sdb6` to the end. Replace `/dev/sdb6`
>      with the acutal device name of your BBP. You can use the commandline
>      editor [nano](https://askubuntu.com/q/54221/40581) to keep things simple.
>
>    Install the GRUB MBR image to the BBP with:
>
>    ```
>    grub-install --boot-directory /mnt/test/boot/ --target i386-pc $device
>    ```
>
>    You might want to remove or comment out the line in
>      `/etc/default/grub` and add it to the actual installation.