# Unable to boot after install - no errors

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, 13.10, 14.10

I have tried to do a single install on a laptop that previously hold Windows 7. I tried to install 64bit desktop version of 14.10, 14.04, and now 13.10 with the same results. Installation from USB works just fine. No errors during installation, but after reboot it just wouldn't start from the Ubuntu partition.

The processor is intel core i5-2410M cpu @ 2.30 Ghz x 4

EDIT from comments: I tried to run a boot-repair and it answers "GPT detected, please create a BIOS-Boot partition..

Comment: 13.10 is no longer supported. I would recommend 14.04 for you over 14.10 only because of the long term support. I you cannot boot after installing, Either you have a corrupt installation ISO verify here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso/503788#503788 or you have made an error somewhere in this process: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks, but the reason trying 13.10 was that none of the other worked.

Comment: The installation works just fine. So it is something with the boot block that is faulty or wrong after coming from a windows environment. I don't think this actually has anything to do with the version of Ubuntu being installed. This is not a dual boot installation and I have tried the installation several times with different images with the same result.

Comment: Does your system have a UEFI BIOS?

Comment: Don't know.  But I tried to run a boot-repair and it answers "GPT detected, please create a BIOS-Boot partition..."

Comment: Try following this GPT answer:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/423723/how-to-resolve-the-gpt-detected-please-create-a-bios-boot-partition-error-whe