# Unable to boot Ubuntu after resizing

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted

I'm a newbie Ubuntu user, and I was using a latest Ubuntu version on my laptop.

I tried to install Windows7 alongside the Ubuntu I was using

I did,

1. I used Gparted from Ubuntu live CD to modify partition.
2. I resized(reduced) the size of the partition with Ubuntu OS in it.
3. After such modification, I am unable to boot Ubuntu - (I suppose my laptop can't access the disk with Ubuntu OS.

(* I didn't installed windows on NTFS yet!, however such problem occured.)

Answer (score 0):

When you install Windows after you installed ubuntu then Windows installs his own boot manager which will boot windows only.
You can fix it with booting from a Linux Live DVD/USB and then reinstall Grub.

Answer (score 0):

OPs answer.

It seems like I have deleted the bios boot partition by mistake.(I realized this fact only after executing "boot-repair". )  and I created the partition - and followed the "boot repair" instructions. This worked fined for me.  I found this to be very relevant as well .

[How to resolve the "GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition" error when using boot-repair?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423723/how-to-resolve-the-gpt-detected-please-create-a-bios-boot-partition-error-whe)