# How to create a partition form terminal

Tags: grubrescue

I have been asking GRUB RESCUE everytime I restart my system, So I finally go to know from a previous thread that :**A small partition has to be created on the disk and marked as a code EF02 "BIOS boot partition".**

Please tell me how to create this partition.

I tried **sudo grub-install /dev/sda3** the error is as follows:

Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.

and I also tried **sudo grub-install /dev/sda** i get this error:

Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.

please help

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve the "GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition" error when using boot-repair?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423723/how-to-resolve-the-gpt-detected-please-create-a-bios-boot-partition-error-whe) See also [''EFI boot partition'' and ''biosgrub'' partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500359/efi-boot-partition-and-biosgrub-partition/501360).

Comment: I will try it and will let you know

Comment: Sounds like you have a very old computer. And what has this question have to do with Ubuntu?