# Used sudo command that I don't understand, want to undo it

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, scripts

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 for the first time, and I've been wrestling with various aspects of it since (mostly successfully), however in attempting to fix and issue with Firefox not playing Youtube videos properly, I used a weird command that's resulted in a whole lot of graphical glitches and I don't understand sudo/bash commands well enough to be able to reverse the effects. I was hoping someone on here might be able to help.

TL;DR: I used a bash command from the internet without quite knowing what it does, and now my computer is behaving oddly.

The command in question: `sudo bash -c "echo export MOZ_USE_OMTC=1 >> /etc/X11/Xsession.d/90environment"`

If someone could tell me how to undo this, I would be very grateful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to run another untrusted `sudo` command:

```
sudo sed -i '/^export MOZ_USE_OMTC=1$/d' /etc/X11/Xsession.d/90environment
```

You have appended a line containing `export MOZ_USE_OMTC=1` to the file `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90environment`. This `sed` command deletes any line which contains exactly that.

Or you could open the file in `nano` to edit it manually:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/Xsession.d/90environment
```

See [How to edit files in a terminal with nano?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54221/how-to-edit-files-in-a-terminal-with-nano).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and that first command worked perfectly. Thank you so much :)