# Mousepad stopped working 12.04

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, asus

please forgive my ignorance, but need some help. My ex installed Ubuntu 12.04lts on my Asus laptop, and everything running well. This morning all good, mousepad working, 2 finger scrolling working, put it into hibernation and on waking mousepad not working.

I found what to put into terminal to make mousepad work again, but was confused by instructions of what to do make it permanently work. And 2 finger scrolling doesn't work and there is no option in mousepad settings.

Any clear directions would be gratefully appreciated as I don't want to have to contact the ex for help....ever!!

Comment: Just a heads up that there is a newer LTS release available and it is recommended to upgrade, even if it won't solve this problem. Also note that using an operating system that an ex boyfriend or girlfriend installed for you is a potential privacy risk.

Comment: will upgrade cause problems? Would i need to back everything up first? Told you I was very new to this!! Am willing to learn.

Comment: And regarding it being a duplicate question, I don't understand how to create the file to make the changes permanent. If you can help I would be grateful.

Comment: You can create and edit files with a text editor like [nano](http://askubuntu.com/q/54221/40581) (`sudo nano filename` in this case) and you should create a backup image http://askubuntu.com/q/110477/40581