# Ubuntu GNOME: Grey screen and very slow boot

Tags: boot, gnome, ubuntu-gnome

On every boot up I get this:

[image: grey screen]

For about 10 seconds (or more) before the "normal" Ubuntu Gnome loading screen and the login screen comes up.

I've read some questions and a bug report about this already, but this problem was dismissed as a minor inconvenience or there were no real solutions (that worked for me). For me, this problem leads to an unacceptable slow boot compared to Ubuntu (Unity) or Windows.

Does anybody know how to fix this or is this a "feature" of Ubuntu Gnome and not a bug?

Comment: Do you see the Grey colored screen *instead* of grub?

Comment: Yes. Only Ubuntu Gnome is installed on this machine, so no grub screen.

Comment: Did the answer fix your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### CLI method

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

And change GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 to GRUB_TIMEOUT=1

```
sudo update-grub
```

---

#### GUI method (mostly)

Install Grub Customizer

To do that, Open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and enter the following commands one by one

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

After installing it open it by this command

```
grub-customizer
```

it might ask you for your password

1. Go to **General Settings** tab
2. Check **Show menu** option under *visibility* (if you want Grub Screen to be visible)
3. Change the value of **Boot default entry after** to be less than *10 Seconds* (I've made it 1 Second)
4. After you're done click on <kbd>Save</kbd> button in upper left corner

Try to reboot your system now, and see if the problem is gone

[image: Grub Customizer window]*Theme might not look like this*

---

More info

[How to edit files in a terminal with nano?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54221/how-to-edit-files-in-a-terminal-with-nano)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to reduce the boot time a bit and the grey screen is gone. After the grub menu it still takes longer than on "normal" Ubuntu (Unity). Is there any way to hide the grub screen AND avoid the grey screen (setting "Boot default entry after" to 0 did not work)?

Comment: @Dreipunkt you'd not wanna do that believe me, Grub is a really important component. you might not need it now but those other advance options and [memory tests](https://superuser.com/a/131604/714344) are important. I believe this is as fast as it can get, if that answer did solve your problem then consider ticking that "accept answer" tick mark, it helps to close down the question