# Grub doesn't show up, just grey screen for seconds instead!

Tags: grub2, ubuntu-gnome

I tried Ubuntu Gnome and liked it and I want to stay on it but It directly boots without Grub screen, But a Grey background with slightly darker borders appear while booting, It takes a lot of time. how can I bring the grub menu back?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/904608/ubuntu-gnome-grey-screen-and-very-slow-boot/904612#904612

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Grub Customizer

To do that, Open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and enter the following commands one by one

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

After installing it open it by this command

```
grub-customizer
```

it might ask you for your password

1. Go to **General Settings** tab
2. Check **Show menu** option under *visibility*
3. After you're done click on <kbd>Save</kbd> button in upper left corner

That should make Grub menu appear while booting

[Original Work](https://askubuntu.com/a/904612/665251)

Comment: Seems to me the same answer with a minor difference, you should flag the question as duplicate if your answer works for this situation ;)

Comment: @Ravexina I tried to flag that question as a duplicate but it didn't came up in the list even after searching by coping and pasting the exact title (strange) , then I thought I should just answer but left the comment to the possible duplicate question in a comment. Can you request a merge, I think they are pretty same and answer will (probably) work

Comment: You could use the exact link to the other question instead of its title . I voted to close the question as duplicate. It's up to other folks to close it too or leave it open.