# Problems with the nano editor

Tags: command-line, nano

When I'm editing in nano, after a while I get the command console inside the editor. I attach an image with the nano problem

[image: Nano editor]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit files in a terminal with nano?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54221/how-to-edit-files-in-a-terminal-with-nano)

Comment: @karel No, the issue is that when I use the nano to edit and I'm inside the file I want to edit and start repeating, it goes out of the editor and shows the console.

Comment: That console thing at the bottom of nano is part of nano text editor and it's supposed to be there.

Comment: Could you clarify your question, please (be more verbose/explicit)? I'm confused, for these reasons: 1. As far as I know, you can't attach images with Nano; it's a text editor; however, I don't know what you meant by attaching images. 2. By editing, what exactly are you doing, and what part of Nano are you doing it in?

Answer (score 1):

I know the error that caused the nano to close automatically and leave me in the command console. The problem is that the file I was accessing was in the container and the status of the container was "Up to 2 minutes (health: start)", which caused the container to restart from time to time and for each restart to exit the editor "nano".

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong (see my comments asking for clarification), but I'm guessing maybe you're typing in the main text area, and you pressed Ctrl+w, or another keyboard shortcut that invoked the option to search. Just press Ctrl+c to cancel and it should take you back.

Ctrl+c doesn't break out of the program, so you don't need to worry about that happening. It's what you press to cancel stuff in Nano.