# Create .netrc-file in WSL/Ubuntu

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am currently trying to get ISCE running and for this task (as I get the error that it is missing) I need to create/edit an (existing) .netrc file.

Unfortunately I am really new to WSL/Ubuntu over all, so I do not know how to do this since I only have the terminal to do stuff.

Would be great if someone can help me/give me a link to somethig I did not find.

Thanks,
Felix

Comment: Does this help --> [How to edit files in a terminal with nano?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54221/how-to-edit-files-in-a-terminal-with-nano)

Comment: Ah I didnt see it before, but thanks for your hint anyways! I used vim to do it (see comment below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create them in your home directory. So

```
vi /home/$USER/.netrc
```

And the contents generally looks like this:

```
machine {remote-server}
login {email}
password {password}
```

ISCE might look for a specific location (but I would assume it will look in /home/$USER/ by default).

Comment: Thank you, I think I was able to do it this way!