# nano ~/.bashrc problems while trying to download kallisto | bustools

Tags: bash, bashrc

Some background information:

---

I am on windows using ubuntu, trying to download kallisto | bustools

Attached is the introductory video made by their team (although they used a MacBook)

**kallisto | bustools: Installation:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thvtp7Ik6ts

I am a high school student, so relatively new to coding/programming (not even sure if that's what I'm doing right now)

---

**My question is this:** Once the guy in the video gets to the part where he types in `nano ~/.bashrc` I try doing the same thing but get this big page giving me a weird message (attached below, with an option for 117 more lines). The thing they got is shown at the 3:00 minute mark in his youtube video.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Thanks!

The 'big page':

```
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
```

Comment: macOS's default `.bashrc` is going to be different from Ubuntu's default bashrc. If you have trouble using `nano` as the editor, use `gedit` instead.

Comment: @muru alright, thank you! Would that compromise anything with the program? I tried doing `gedit ~/.bashrc` but got an "unable to init server...." message. Is there some sort of alternative?

Comment: Oh, you're on WSL. In that case, best learn how to use nano: https://askubuntu.com/q/54221/158442. As for .bashrc, just out your additions at the end of the file. If they ask you to *change* a line instead, post the suggested changes in the question and we can help you adapt them to Ubuntu's bashrc