# Need to cancel a scheduled shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I'm very new to ubuntu. I am trying to cancel a shutdown I accidently put using the command `echo "0 3 * * * root /sbin/shutdown -h 5 'system will reboot in 5 minutes'" | sudo tee /etc/cron.d/reboot-at-3am` How can I stop this from shutting down. I wanted it to reboot at 3am but it is just shutting down and not restarting.

Comment: You will need to edit your `reboot-at-3am` file to say `shutdown -R` if you want to reboot. `-h` means "hard" 

Comment: How do i Edit it?

Comment: sorry that was supposed to be 0 3

Comment: Here's one example of how to edit a text file: https://askubuntu.com/questions/54221/how-to-edit-files-in-a-terminal-with-nano

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
shutdown -c
```

to cancel the pending shutdown and correct your command

Comment: Seems like this would only work during the fraction of a second after cron reads the crontab *that minute*. Cron doesn't run commands in advance.

Comment: when i try that i get Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required

Comment: @Sidewinder did you run it with `sudo` or as `root`?