# VIM, ESC key doesn't work - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, vim, git

I'm using Git to control the different versions of my project. When reverting to a previous commit it shows a VIM terminal as expected.

Theoretically I should press ESC  to write  my command, but ESC key doesn't respond, and therefore I cannot give any command to VIM. It is the same in all my projects.
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 in a Lenovo ideapad.

Any help is really appreciated.

[the VIM terminal that appears when trying to git revert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B99kK.png)

Comment: looks like nano to me -- not vim

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot that you have shared appears to be a `nano` text editor and not VIM.

See for example [How to edit files in a terminal with nano?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54221/how-to-edit-files-in-a-terminal-with-nano)

Comment: Thanks. Do you think it's safe to set it up as the default editor?
ubuntu sudo editor=vim

Comment: @Genis you could do for git only with `git config --global core.editor "vim"` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2596835/14467607) for more details)