# Fix "sudo apt --fix-broken install" "sudo apt remove libc6:amd64" "sudo dpkg --configure -a" and can not delete packages in Ubuntu20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

CONCLUSION: Thank you all who helped me in this problem. Now I have tried nearly all related methods but still can not figure it out.

So I plan to reinstall the whole system.

P.S. NEVER STOP a processing program, or you will have the same problem with me.

---

Question:

I actually tried many many methods but still not figure it out. Anyone can help me?

My system is Ubuntu 20.04, when I run the code below

`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

I got an error message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libopencc2 libopencc2-data
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  locales
The following NEW packages will be installed
  locales
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/6,592 kB of archives.
After this operation, 17.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 package libc6:amd64 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to remove

`sudo apt remove libc6:amd64`

The I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 accountsservice : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 acl : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 acpid : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but it is not going to be installed
 activity-log-manager : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 alsa-utils : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but it is not going to be installed
 anacron : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
 apg : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 apparmor : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
 appstream : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 apt : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
 apt-utils : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 aspell : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 at-spi2-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
 avahi-autoipd : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 avahi-daemon : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but it is not going to be installed
 avahi-utils : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 bamfdaemon : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 baobab : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 base-files : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.4) but it is not going to be installed
 base-passwd : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
 bash : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
 bc : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 bind9-dnsutils : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 bind9-host : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 bind9-libs : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
 binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but it is not going to be installed
 blender : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but it is not going to be installed
 bluez : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
 bluez-cups : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
 bluez-obexd : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.28) but it is not going to be installed
 bolt : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.28) but it is not going to be installed
 brightnessctl : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but it is not going to be installed
 brltty : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but it is not going to be installed
 bsdmainutils : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 bsdutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
 bubblewrap : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
 busybox-initramfs : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.28) but it is not going to be installed
 bzip2 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 cheese : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 colord : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but it is not going to be installed
 compiz-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 compiz-gnome : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
 compiz-plugins-default : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but it is not going to be installed
 copyq : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 coreutils : PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.28) but it is not going to be installed
 cpio : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
 cpp-9 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 cracklib-runtime : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 crda : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
 cron : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
 cups : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
 cups-browsed : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
 cups-bsd : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 cups-client : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
 cups-core-drivers : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
 cups-daemon : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
 cups-filters : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but it is not going to be installed
 cups-filters-core-drivers : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
...TOO LONG SO I JUST CUT THE START AND THE END...
 xserver-xorg-video-qxl : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 xserver-xorg-video-radeon : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
 xserver-xorg-video-vesa : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 xserver-xorg-video-vmware : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 xwayland : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but it is not going to be installed
 xxd : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.4) but it is not going to be installed
 xz-utils : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
 yelp : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 zeitgeist-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 zeitgeist-datahub : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 zenity : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 zip : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 zlib1g : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Can anyone help me?

###### UPDATE

When I run

`sudo apt install --reinstall libc6:amd64`

I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 language-pack-en-base : Depends: locales (>= 2.3.6) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-en-base : Depends: locales (>= 2.3.6) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-zh-hans-base : Depends: locales (>= 2.3.6) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-zh-hans-base : Depends: locales (>= 2.3.6) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-l10n-en-gb : Depends: locales but it is not going to be installed or
                                   locales-all
 libreoffice-l10n-en-za : Depends: locales but it is not going to be installed or
                                   locales-all
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then I run

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

I got

```
dpkg: error processing package libc6:i386 (--configure):
 package libc6:i386 cannot be configured because libc6:amd64 is not ready (current status 'half-installed')
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcrypt1:i386:
 libcrypt1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.25); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcrypt1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libc-bin:
 libc-bin depends on libc6 (>> 2.31); however:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not installed.
 libc-bin depends on libc6 (<< 2.32); however:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for man-db:
 man-db depends on libc6 (>= 2.28); however:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package man-db (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:i386
 libcrypt1:i386
 libc-bin
 man-db
```

When I tried

`sudo aptitude reinstall libc6:amd64`

It shows

```
sudo: aptitude: command not found
```

Then, I tried

`sudo apt-get install aptitude`

I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 aptitude : Depends: aptitude-common (= 0.8.12-1ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcwidget4 (>= 0.5.18-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libparse-debianchangelog-perl but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-en-base : Depends: locales (>= 2.3.6) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-en-base : Depends: locales (>= 2.3.6) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-zh-hans-base : Depends: locales (>= 2.3.6) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-zh-hans-base : Depends: locales (>= 2.3.6) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-l10n-en-gb : Depends: locales but it is not going to be installed or
                                   locales-all
 libreoffice-l10n-en-za : Depends: locales but it is not going to be installed or
                                   locales-all
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

A loop again.

###### UPDATED

I tried

`sudo apt update`

I got

```
Hit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Get:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]   
Get:4 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [2,384 kB]
Hit:5 https://typora.io ./linux/ InRelease                                     
Hit:6 https://typora.io/linux ./ InRelease                                     
Hit:7 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]      
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hluk/copyq/ubuntu focal InRelease               
Get:10 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [788 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [59.9 kB]
Get:13 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [274 kB]
Get:14 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [712 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [94.1 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]
Get:17 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,026 kB]
Get:18 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [408 kB]
Get:19 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [23.6 kB]
Get:20 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]
Get:21 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [8,000 B]
Get:22 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [30.5 kB]
Hit:12 https://archive.ubuntukylin.com/ukui focal InRelease                    
Fetched 6,146 kB in 5s (1,359 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up-to-date.
W: Conflicting distribution: https://typora.io ./linux/ InRelease (expected ./linux/ but got )
```

Then I tried

`grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

I got

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20220831)]/ focal main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://typora.io ./linux/
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src https://typora.io ./linux/
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://typora.io/linux ./
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src https://typora.io/linux ./
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntukylin.com/ukui focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://archive.ubuntukylin.com/ukui focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/hluk-ubuntu-copyq-focal.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/hluk/copyq/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/hluk-ubuntu-copyq-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/hluk/copyq/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/hluk-ubuntu-copyq-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/hluk/copyq/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/hluk-ubuntu-copyq-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/hluk/copyq/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Then I tried

`apt-cache policy libc6:amd64 libc6:i386 libcrypt1:i386 libcrypt1:amd64`

I got

```
libc6:
  Installed: 2.31-0ubuntu9.9
  Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.9
  Version table:
 *** 2.31-0ubuntu9.9 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.31-0ubuntu9.7 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.31-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
libc6:i386:
  Installed: 2.31-0ubuntu9.9
  Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.9
  Version table:
 *** 2.31-0ubuntu9.9 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.31-0ubuntu9.7 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages
     2.31-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
libcrypt1:i386:
  Installed: 1:4.4.10-10ubuntu4
  Candidate: 1:4.4.10-10ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.4.10-10ubuntu4 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libcrypt1:
  Installed: 1:4.4.10-10ubuntu4
  Candidate: 1:4.4.10-10ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.4.10-10ubuntu4 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Then I tried

`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libopencc2 libopencc2-data
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  locales
The following NEW packages will be installed
  locales
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/6,592 kB of archives.
After this operation, 17.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 package libc6:amd64 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

UPDATE--------------------------------------------------------------------

I tried

```
sudo apt reinstall --fix-broken libc6:amd64
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 language-pack-en-base : Depends: locales (>= 2.3.6) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-en-base : Depends: locales (>= 2.3.6) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-zh-hans-base : Depends: locales (>= 2.3.6) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-zh-hans-base : Depends: locales (>= 2.3.6) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-l10n-en-gb : Depends: locales but it is not going to be installed or
                                   locales-all
 libreoffice-l10n-en-za : Depends: locales but it is not going to be installed or
                                   locales-all
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

I got

```
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied
```

I tried

```
deb https://typora.io/linux ./
```

I got

```
Command 'deb' not found, did you mean:

  command 'den' from snap den (1.2.0-0)
  command 'dub' from snap dub (1.19.0)
  command 'edb' from deb edb-debugger (1.0.0-1build3)
  command 'dab' from deb bsdgames (2.17-28build1)
  command 'dub' from deb dub (1.19.0-1build2.1)
  command 'derb' from deb icu-devtools (66.1-2ubuntu2.1)
  command 'debi' from deb devscripts (2.20.2ubuntu2)
  command 'debc' from deb devscripts (2.20.2ubuntu2)
  command 'dex' from deb dex (0.8.0-2)
  command 'dep' from deb go-dep (0.5.4-3ubuntu0.1)
  command 'deb3' from deb quilt (0.65-3)

See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
```

I tried to edit

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

I got

```
/etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied
```

and can not save the read only file.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall libc6:amd64`

Comment: There is a very crucial conflict with the packages on your system. `libc6` is a very important library required by all the system packages in Ubuntu. Try the command suggested by @Jarno and report further. Generally, a very simple solution to issues which include half-configured packages is `dpkg -P` but libc6 is a critical package on your system and is used by many other packages, so removing it may cause other issues. `sudo dpkg --configure -a` give this a try too.

Comment: @AlwaysAvailable Hi I already updated the results, could you please help me to check with them?

Comment: @jarno Hi Jarno, I updated the results of the command, could you please help me to check with them?

Comment: Try `sudo aptitude reinstall libc6:amd64`

Comment: @AlwaysAvailable Hey I updated the results. It seems a loop again.

Comment: `sudo apt update` and `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` also `apt-cache policy libc6:amd64 libc6:i386 libcrypt1:i386 libcrypt1:amd64`  please.

Comment: @nobody Hi I updated results, please check them.

Comment: Well, I have got something in my pocket which might be a piece of cake solution to your problem but because of the **risk involved I suggest you listen to @nobody and other folk's views before trying**: `systemctl list-dependencies libc6` review, and stop the crucial one's by `sudo systemctl stop <service_name>` and then `sudo dpkg --configure --force-all libc6:amd64` and then restart the services you closed before by `sudo systemctl start <service_name>`; it might cause further and long terms conflict (**notice I used the 'may' modal**); so try other options first.

Comment: Could you try `sudo apt reinstall --fix-broken libc6:amd64`?

Comment: If you are trying to reinstall the system them might as well give my command a try

Comment: you have to open  /etc/apt/sources.list with an editor and change the line with granted rights. Thats not meant as command. `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources .list` https://askubuntu.com/questions/54221/how-to-edit-files-in-a-terminal-with-nano

Comment: It is odd that the system is not going to install "locales" package even if it is a dependency. What does `apt policy locales` give?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with apt.

My solution was running `sudo apt-get update`.

After that apt was working properly!

So try this command and then run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: Hi Ivan, I have updated the results when I run the command.

Comment: Sometimes due to an update/modification in the repository list; some packages are not identified as installed or are considered 3rd party cause of which becomes this error; but that's very specific and does not seem to be applicable in situations such as this

Answer (score 0):

I give a try.

Please in

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

change entry

```
deb https://typora.io/linux ./
```

to

```
#deb https://typora.io/linux ./
```

apt gives a warning about this entry.
Then  change from mirror-server to main-server

```
sudo sed -i s,//au.archive,//archive,g  /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Now we let apt forget what was available on your mirror-sever.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

the same for dpkg.

```
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
```

Please check with

```
sudo ls -al /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/
```

if this folder is empty. If not remove the content but only the content.

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*
```

Now procdeed

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -f install
```

Sidenote: it is always a good idea to have a current backup from important data.

Comment: Oddly the output of `sudo apt update` did also list `Hit:5 https://typora.io ./linux/ InRelease`

Comment: According to my testing the the line to delete in /etc/apt/sources.list is `deb https://typora.io ./linux/` and there is no need to touch line `deb https://typora.io/linux ./`. The former line does not work even if you remove the latter one.

Comment: Even typora.io website does tell to add the latter one: https://typora.io/#linux

Comment: Anyway I think that _typora_ repository is not causing the issue with `apt install`. At least it did not do that as I tested installing _typora_ in 20.04.