# Dark mode on Xournal++

Tags: configuration, git

Recently I installed Xournal++ in Ubuntu. I came across [this link](https://github.com/juansegaes/xournalpp-nord) for a cool nord theme. I tried to install this to my Xournal++ application, but I am a complete newbie to both Linux and GitHub so I have zero idea about what to do. I did however install the Git application with `sudo apt install git`, but I'm not sure what to do after this.


Edit:
The entire time I thought that the entire interface including toolbar will turn black with the theme. But only later realised that the above theme only changes ink colours and not the interface. I then changed the Appearance on Settings from Light to Dark mode. Now the interface is in Dark mode. Thanks to all who helped

Comment: I installed the file and opened terminal from .xournal but when I copy the code from the .ini file an enter it into terminal and error pops up `bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`('` what  now?

Comment: "and entered it on terminal." It is not mentioned in the instructions that you should do that.

Comment: Maybe a good (learning) thing to do is read: [How to edit files in a terminal with nano?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54221/how-to-edit-files-in-a-terminal-with-nano).

Comment: @Raffa: Who is judging? I am only (trying to) giving some advice, to become more knowledgeable using Linux/Ubuntu.

Comment: @Luuk Fair enough :-) ... Comment retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which package manager (*SNAP or APT*) you used to install [Xournal++](https://xournalpp.github.io/), you can simply add the [xournalpp-nord](https://github.com/juansegaes/xournalpp-nord) theme as follows:

##### SNAP installed

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/juansegaes/xournalpp-nord/main/toolbar.ini \
>> ~/snap/xournalpp/current/.config/xournalpp/toolbar.ini
```

##### APT installed

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/juansegaes/xournalpp-nord/main/toolbar.ini \
>> ~/.config/xournalpp/toolbar.ini
```

---

**Notice** that what the above two commands do is append the contents of this [`toolbar.ini`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/juansegaes/xournalpp-nord/main/toolbar.ini) to the files `~/snap/xournalpp/current/.config/xournalpp/toolbar.ini` and `~/.config/xournalpp/toolbar.ini` respectively (*creating the file if it doesn't exist*) ... The same thing can be done alternatively by editing those files and manually adding the content.