# How to create swap partition on already installed ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, swap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding swap partition after system installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/adding-swap-partition-after-system-installation)

i have already installed ubuntu 11.04 without any swap partition. Now i want to create swap partition which should be utilized by this os. i have tried creating one by partitioning but ubuntu can not use this swap memory and swap usage remains unused.
please tell me how to make it usable by ubuntu.

Comment: see here http://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/adding-swap-partition-after-system-installation your same problem

Answer (score 35, accepted):

see here [How do I add a swap partition after system installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/adding-swap-partition-after-system-installation) your same situation

To create a swap partition after an Ubuntu installation create an empty partition that should have no holes. You can then format this partition with

```
sudo mkswap /dev/sdx
```

replacing sdx with your partition. Mount this partition as swap with

```
sudo swapon -U UUID
```

where UUID is that of your /dev/sdx as read from this

```
blkid /dev/sdx
```

Bind your new swap in /etc/fstab by adding this line:

```
UUID=xxx    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

If you want to use your swap for hibernating then you need to update the UUID in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` with this content RESUME=UUID=xxx. Don't forget to `sudo update-initramfs -u`.

**I take no responsibility if something goes wrong.**