# I can't create both Swap and Ext4 partition

Tags: swap, ext4

I installed Ubuntu using the dual boot method. My laptop is HP pavilion DV6. It has MBR  on my HDD, so I'm limited to create 4 primary partitions. In Windows 8 I have used 4 primary partitions. In the driver management I see only 3 primary partitions which are the C, D, E drive. The F drive is logical drive. I didn't find the missing primary partition so I deleted my D drive and thus made space for a new primary partition.

When I began to install Ubuntu I created only 1 partition. I could either create a swap partition or a Ext4. So I decided to create an Ext4 partion which will replace the D drive partition. But i think i should create a swap Partition for my Ubuntu.

What should I do now, my laptop has 4GB RAM.

Here is my gparted snapshot.

[image: gparted snapshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make logical partitions, they require one of your primary partition slots to be used as the base for the extended volume.

In this case, /dev/sda3 is the base for extended volumes, but /dev/sda5 is the only logical partition in there, and is using up the whole of /dev/sda3's storage.

Hope that helps!

EDIT:

The first answer on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103043/how-to-create-swap-partition-on-already-installed-ubuntu) should show you how to enable the partition for use as swap.

Comment: so i should free some space from /dev/sda5 then i can add some space for my swap partition ??

Comment: i shrinked /dev/sda5 then created swap partition. please check this snapshot is this ok?? http://i.imgur.com/l4xA0Ia.png

Comment: when i executed 'top' command i saw there is 0KiB in the swap area. can you explain this ??
snapshot http://i.imgur.com/iuw3AzL.png

Answer (score 2):

4gb ram is enough and there is no need of `swap` still if you want swap Shrink `/dev/sda5` and create a logical volume of type `swap`.