# how do i add swap memory to already installed ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, ram, swap

I recently installed Ubuntu and in the process of completion i realized that i had not dedicated a swap memory during installation. How can i go about adding the swap memory without reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version?

Comment: You can also look inside /etc/fstab and it will tell you if you have a swap file or partition and ive it's UUID.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `ls -al /swapfile` and a screenshot of `gparted` and then I can make the best recommendation. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 3):

Recent versions of Ubuntu install a swap file rather than a dedicated swap partition. So likely, you do have swap. Check the status of your swap with the command

```
swapon
```

If you have a swap file in use, you eventually [can change the size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075505/how-do-i-increase-swapfile-in-ubuntu-18-04).

If you do not have swap, then you can add it after installation. The easiest is [to add a swap file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075505/how-do-i-increase-swapfile-in-ubuntu-18-04). [Adding a swap partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103043/how-to-create-swap-partition-on-already-installed-ubuntu) requires you to change the drive partitioning. Typically, you reduce an existing partition or delete a partition to create free space, in which you can create a swap partition.

In both cases, you need to "declare" the swap space in the configuration file `/etc/fstab` for it to be used as swap.

For a swap file, you need to add a line like:

```
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
```

You need to provide the actual name of your swap file if you did not create it as `swapfile` in the root directory (`/`).

For a swap partition, you need to identify the UUID of your swap partition and then refer to that partition by UUID as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103043/how-to-create-swap-partition-on-already-installed-ubuntu) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-swap-after-system-installation).