# New SWAP partition: help to recognize?

Tags: swap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding swap partition after system installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/adding-swap-partition-after-system-installation)

Somehow I loaded 12.04 onto my netbook with no swap partition and I've tried to make a new one.

It's on a separate partition from the boot partition and I haven't found a way to have it recognized yet.  I don't understand the code I've read online and hope there's a program with a GUI that can help me with this.

If not, can anyone explain to me how I can have a swapspace on this netbook

Answer (score 0):

Not positive about this, but I think this is right:

Now that you have the partition, let's assume it's `/dev/hdb1`

Let's make it a swap: `mkswap /dev/hdb1`

Now let's activate it: `swapon /dev/hdb1`

Let's update our fstab file to make it activate on boot: `gksu gedit  /etc/fstab`

add this line: `/dev/hdb1       none    swap    sw      0       0`

I THINK that should work, and the community will correct me where I went wrong.  Good luck!

Comment: i tried but it denied me permission.  groan.

Comment: Did you try sudo?  Where exactly are you getting the permission error?

Comment: I just did.  newb - oldrob.

I now have a ridiculously large swap partition (9.8 GB) and it's recognized in the system monitor as active.  none of it's being used yet but it's there if I the system needs it.