# How can I list the hard drive and all its partitions including size from terminal?

Tags: server, hard-drive, command-line

I have Ubuntu server 12.04 installed with no GUI. I would like to list my hard drive and it's partitions along with how big each partition is using the command line.

Comment: did you try my commands ?

Comment: I tried all but inxi because my internet is down right now so I couldn't install it. All the other options were exactly what I was looking for and they each have there own perks, thank you.

Comment: ok hope you are ok now

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I view all available HDD's/partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/q/182446/253474)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are a few ways:

- If you have an MBR partition table:

  ```
  terdon@oregano ~ $ sudo fdisk -l
  Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
  255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
  Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disk identifier: 0x4b66b5d5

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/sda1              63       80324       40131   de  Dell Utility
  /dev/sda2   *       81920    30801919    15360000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda3        30801920   194643539    81920810    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda4       194643601   976773119   391064759+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
  /dev/sda5       194643603   198836504     2096451    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
  /dev/sda6       342951936   960387071   308717568   83  Linux
  /dev/sda7       198840320   342949887    72054784   83  Linux
  /dev/sda8       960389120   976773119     8192000   82  Linux swap / Solaris
  ```

  or
      sudo sfdidk -l

  These do not give particularly human readable output though. The next choices are better.
- For both GPT and MBR partition tables:

  ```
  terdon@oregano ~ $ sudo parted -l
  Model: ATA ST9500420AS (scsi)
  Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
  Partition Table: msdos

  Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
   1      32.3kB  41.1MB  41.1MB  primary   fat16           diag
   2      41.9MB  15.8GB  15.7GB  primary   ntfs            boot
   3      15.8GB  99.7GB  83.9GB  primary   ntfs
   4      99.7GB  500GB   400GB   extended                  lba
   5      99.7GB  102GB   2147MB  logical   fat32           lba
   7      102GB   176GB   73.8GB  logical   ext4
   6      176GB   492GB   316GB   logical   ext4
   8      492GB   500GB   8389MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


  Model: ST950032 5AS (scsi)
  Disk /dev/sdb: 500GB
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
  Partition Table: msdos

  Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
   1      32.3kB  500GB  500GB  primary  ntfs
  ```
- `lsblk`

  ```
  terdon@oregano ~ $ lsblk
  NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
  sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
  ├─sda1   8:1    0  39.2M  0 part 
  ├─sda2   8:2    0  14.7G  0 part 
  ├─sda3   8:3    0  78.1G  0 part 
  ├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
  ├─sda5   8:5    0     2G  0 part 
  ├─sda6   8:6    0 294.4G  0 part /home
  ├─sda7   8:7    0  68.7G  0 part /
  └─sda8   8:8    0   7.8G  0 part [SWAP]
  sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
  └─sdb1   8:17   0 465.8G  0 part /test
  sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
  ```
- [Install `inxi`](http://code.google.com/p/inxi/wiki/Installation) then run

  ```
  terdon@oregano ~ $ inxi -D
  Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (70.1% used) 1: id: /dev/sda model: ST9500420AS size: 500.1GB 
             2: id: /dev/sdb model: 5AS size: 500.1GB
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Here's couple of other approaches:

**lshw**

The short version of `lshw`  conveniently lists the size of disks in the description

```
sudo lshw -short | awk '/disk|volume/'            
/0/1/0.0.0    /dev/sda    disk        120GB Radeon R7
/0/1/0.0.0/1  /dev/sda1   volume      111GiB EXT4 volume
/0/2/0.0.0    /dev/cdrom  disk        DVDRAM GT20N
```

And for more detailed info use `lshw -class volume,disk`

**udiscsctl**

`udiscsctl` has `info` option which coupled with `-b` (for block-device) flag, can show detailed information. Using a simple for loop and `awk`, we can make it show partition and size information specifically. Here is my example:

```
$ for device in /dev/sd* ; do udisksctl info  -b $device | awk '/[[:blank:]]Device:/; /Size/' ;done                
    Device:                     /dev/sda
    Size:                       120034123776
    Device:                     /dev/sda1
    Size:                       120032591872
    Size:               120032591872
```

**df command**

`df` command shows information about all currently mounted filesystems. Again, we can use this command directly, but also clean up the output using `awk`

```
df -h | awk 'NR==1 ;/\/dev\/sd*/'                                                                                
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       110G   68G   37G  66% /
```

Here we just print the header and use -h flag that makes size be printed in human-readable format

**/sys/class/block/sd* files**

Inside `/sys/class/block/` folder you will find files related to block devices( which typically refer to physical memory devices ) . In particular we want to focus on any file that starts with `sd` letters.

For instance, I have one hard drive with only one partition. Thus `/sys/class/block/sda` refers to my whole hard-drive, while `/sys/class/block/sda1` refers to my Ubuntu partition.

Inside each folder for each device, you will find the `size` file , which lists *how many blocks of 512 MB there are on the device*. So the true size is `number of blocks x 521`.

Again, with little command line magic, we get:

```
$ for device in /sys/class/block/sd*; do printf "%s " $device; bc <<< "$(cat $device/size)*512" ; done             
/sys/class/block/sda 120034123776
/sys/class/block/sda1 120032591872
```

Or a bit shorter with `awk`:

```
$ awk '{print substr(FILENAME,18)" "$1*512}' /sys/class/block/sd*/size                                             
sda/size 120034123776
sda1/size 120032591872
```

Answer (score 0):

In terminal :

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Type your password.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPRg3.png]

`lsblk` command :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7egAM.png]

Comment: Why not copy paste instead of posting the images? That would fasten up loading this answer.

Comment: i think images would be better for understanding

Comment: I agree with you about the images thing, my brain just likes them better.

Comment: On the other hand, images don't let you copy/paste if necessary (not very relevant here, I know) and they really slow down the page which can be important for slow connections.

Answer (score 0):

I got to this by searching "ubuntu server list gpt partitions". I was searching for an answer when using 16.04.1 LTS. For those of you who want to list partitions (MBR or GPT), fdisk seems to have support for both (and not just MBR as in earlier Ubuntu versions) in 16.04.1 LTS. Also `parted` isn't installed by default when the "basic system utilities" option is selected during install. So the following command is all you need on 16.04.1 LTS:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```