# Does ubuntu server uninstall windows?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, windows-10

Non tech here, was trying to install ubuntu to flash drive and boot without installing like I've done before...
Downloaded ubuntu onto new flash, loaded it and there was no option to run without installing so I clicked install.

Desktop GUI wasn't included, wifi not connected and looks like I installed THE SERVER.

Is Windows 10 gone, did I uninstall it? How can I switch back to it if not?

Edit: Not duplicate of the below question because I didn't click "replace windows with ubuntu". Nor did I attempt to keep one drive while removing the other. I thought I was uploading desktop ubuntu, was still asleep and clicked through, it's ubuntu server. I clicked under partition to use the space available, rather than reorganizing fragmented spaces into one space. Didn't think it would erase the rest of windows.

Comment: Hmm, best thing to do would probably be boot a normal live image and examine the partitioning state with the included `gparted` program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu) and [How can I list the hard drive and all its partitions including size from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431505/how-can-i-list-the-hard-drive-and-all-its-partitions-including-size-from-termina)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but being a non-tech I don't know what that means.

Comment: I didn't select any option to replace windows during setup but under partition I didn't reorganize the available space to put Linux all together.

Comment: Instead I clicked "use all space available " or something like that

Comment: Can you boot Windows?

Comment: No there are only ubuntu, advanced options for ubuntu and system setup

Comment: That is, those are the potions at startup. Sorry for posting all these  one line posts.

Comment: Booting into boot manager with f12 gives me one option for "ubuntu(ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB)" and a second option which fails to boot for "EFI PXE Network".

Comment: Regarding my suggestion of `gparted`, just boot a normal (non-server) live image, and in the dock search for "Gparted". Open the program, and please post a screenshot of what it displays.

Comment: Appreciate the advice, I would try to do that, but my wireless and Ethernet drivers are disabled, don't seem to have the packages to do anything, can't get them through windows since I don't have it anymore, can't get them in the terminal since I don't have internet.

Comment: Trying to figure out what I can do, didn't even want unintuitive server in the first place, thought I was installing ubuntu desktop like I used from the flash drive before. Is it possible to get a 'live image' under the above circumstances? Totally out of my depth.

Comment: For example "the program 'gparted ' is not installed. You can install it by typing ..." [i do it] ... "unable to locate package gparted"

Comment: @user803674 A live image is what you put on a USB drive to "Try without installing", like you were trying to do in the first place.

Comment: @user803674 But honestly, I think you're in over your head. As far as I'm aware, the Ubuntu Server installer is CLI-based and not intuitive for a novice, and there is no "use available space" option during installation. So where you may have overwritten Windows and any data you had stored on Windows partitions, you may want to seek more in-depth support.

Comment: Ok I will have to find a secure computer to do that from now that windows is unaccessible

Comment: The question in the duplicate might not be the path you took, but the result is the same: your Windows is gone and the more you try booting / creating files in Ubuntu, the less likelyhood you have of recovering any data...