# How can I make myself the owner of a partition?

Tags: partitioning, permissions

So I installed it on a dual-boot on my Main drive, with the intention of this space being for the os and a few programs as this is my SSD with less space. I went back later and used GParted to make another partition for stuff I want to install on ubuntu on another hard drive, I have done this, and now I'm back in Ubuntu but I can't do anything to the drive as the owner is root.

I've looked online for help with this but all I can find is how to edit individual files on a root drive. how do I permanently become the owner?

if relevant the file system type is ext3/ext4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change owner of internal hard drive partition from root to user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43570/change-owner-of-internal-hard-drive-partition-from-root-to-user) and [How can I list the hard drive and all its partitions including size from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431505/)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the following will answer your question:

[Change owner of internal hard drive partition from root to user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43570/change-owner-of-internal-hard-drive-partition-from-root-to-user)

It says:

> If the partition is called party, your user is called cyrex and it is in /media just do for example:
>
> `sudo chown cyrex:cyrex /media/cyrex/party -R (The R is for recursive so it affects all directory/files and subdirectory.`

This would help you locate your drive:

[How can I list the hard drive and all its partitions including size from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431505/how-can-i-list-the-hard-drive-and-all-its-partitions-including-size-from-termina)

It says:

> If you have an MBR partition table:
>
> `sudo fdisk -l`
>
> For both GPT and MBR partition tables:
>
> ?`sudo parted -l`

Comment: thanks, but it still isnt working, i'm doing sudo chown simon:simon /media/simon/1c512beb-7a97-4cf3-a4c9-70b77521ed -R as my terminal says that partition is that but it is saying their is no such file or directory. i have also tried it with /dev/sdb2 infront of it. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: is your partition really "/media/simon/1c"

Comment: i used the command in the second link "lsblk" and got the mount point from the partition.

Comment: Sorry, I'd edited my previous comment - you can look at http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/fdisk-command-to-manage-disk-partitions-in-linux to get the list - `sudo fdisk -l`