# How to get back data after Ubuntu installation?

Tags: 12.04

My friend's laptop was running Windows. It crashed (viruses), so I suggested him to install Ubuntu. Which thing I did (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS).

Before installation, had 3 partitions:

- C:\  Where the system (Windows XP)  was installed
- D:\  Where some data were saved
- E:\  Empty

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on C:\ (by erasing existing Windows). I took 1G from E:\ and I used it for swap. After installation were complete, I run `dh -h` in order to see where is my former D:\ and get back the data of my friend. I got this:

```
Filesystem         Size    Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1          145G    2.4G  135G  2% /
udev               473G    4,0K  473G   1% /dev
tmpfs              193M    844K  192M   1% /run
none               5,0M       0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none               482M    156K  482M   1% /run/shm
```

I run :

```
lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
```

I got this:

```
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda           232.9G            
|-sda1        146.5G /          
|-sda2            1K            
|-sda3          9.3G [SWAP]     
`-sda5         43.2G            
sr0            1024M
```

I remember when I tested Ubuntu (before installing it) the data was on `sda5`

Is there a way to find it and get the data of my friend back ?

Comment: Please post the result of the [lsblk command](http://askubuntu.com/a/333604/356018)

Comment: If that drive is not mounted, `df -h` will not show it. Could you open gparted, and show us what's in there?

Comment: @SirSubstance Thank you for the suggestion. I edited the output of your command

Comment: You said the data was on sda5 before, mount it & see what's there now? And next time, always backup data BEFORE installing an OS!

Comment: @Xen2050 I mounted that partition and I see now the data of my friend. I will save it into a USB key. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: You've welcome. I should've put the comment as an answer, maybe get some rep ;-) maybe I will yet

Comment: @SirSubstance I upvote on one of your former answers as a reward to your help because the command you gave me was the key of the solution. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said the data was on sda5 before, it's still showing up in lsblk. Try to mount it & see what's there now?

And next time, always backup data BEFORE installing an OS! Sometimes it overwrites the wrong data, by mistake or bug.

Comment: No problem, lost data's stressful, especially a friend's data.