# how to access my windows xp files after installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu as dual-boot with Windows XP and now I am unable to boot in to Windows XP and boots straight in to Ubuntu?

Comment: Please show us the contents of `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL` (http://askubuntu.com/a/333604/15811 ) and I sure hope you made a backup... looks like you formatted the XP partition (Windows partitions are accessible and automatically mounted from the file browser if they are present; and our bootloader will show Windows it is is there).

Comment: have you tried BOOT REPAIR[link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repa)

Answer (score 0):

this might helps you... [BOOT-REPAIR](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) helps alot .
you can follow these steps

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`