# Ubuntu Read Write External Harddrive Mac - MountPoint Unclear

Tags: mount, hard-drive, mac, read-only

This is a very basic thing and I cannot get my Ubuntu on mac book pro to write mac external hard drive. It is read only.

I followed the instruction on the website below in parentheses and reached

`sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force`,`rw /dev/sdxy /media/mntpoint`

([How to read and write HFS+ journaled external HDD in Ubuntu without access to OS X?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os))
What is `/media/mntpoint` and what do i put in the code?

Therefore I cannot get my mac external hard drive to write. It can only read.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/media/mntpoint` is just a folder on your hard drive where the mount command is going to mount the partition of the drive to.  Look on your hard drive and look in the `/media` folder.  You should see other folders in there that are mount points.  You can create a folder for that mount point of your choosing.

An example:

```
mkdir -p /media/mac
```

the above line would create a folder called `mac` in the `/media` folder that you can use to mount your Mac drive to.

So, the mount command would then be:

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdxy /media/mac
```

where you would now access the folders on that drive in the `/media/mac` folder on the drive.  Once in that folder you should be the contents of the Mac drive.

If it is already mounted, try the following line to remount the drive:

```
sudo mount -f hfsplus -o remount,force,rw /dev/sdc2
```

this is assuming that `/dev/sdc2` is your Mac drive partition.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It now says "mount: can't find dev/sdc2/media/mac in etc/fstab

Comment: @jasonchang Did you put the space between `/dev/sdc2` and `/media/mac`?

Comment: @jasonchang The `/dev/sdc2` should be the partition and number of the Macintosh drive.  The `/media/mac` is the mount folder on your present drive.  Make sure that you're choosing the right drive to mount.    Take a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/182446/how-do-i-view-all-available-hdds-partitions) to list all your partitions of your drives.

Comment: It now says "/dev/sdc2 is already mounted on /media/ubuntu/My Passport for Mac. But when I go to file, new folder, the option is still grayed out

Comment: @jasonchang That is because it has been mounted as `Read Only`.   Updated answer for remount command.

Comment: @jasonchang The updated answer has that info in it.  The part of the line that is `-o remount,force,rw` the `rw` is `Read Write`.

Comment: Wow. It works. Howcome you folks are so nice. I spent 1 whole day trying to figure out nautilus so I have root permission. Now with your help, I got hfs to read and write. I can now recover data. Thanks so much.