# Reading HFS+ Journaled filesystem in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: hfs+

Disks recognizes the device is available but reports the partition as unused (does not recognized HFS+ file system). When I try to mount the drive, Ubuntu wanders off into limbo reporting nothing. When I try fsck.hfsplus, again Ubuntu wanders off into limbo without reporting anything. After 20 minutes I gave up and closed the console window.

I only tried hfsplus after I fount out that the Paragon Software driver I paid for never worked with the actual release (they only used an alpha test released and never updated after the actual release).

I only want to salvage my data. I am in the process of coping all my data to NTFS. I was using Windows but the latest Paragon Software put Windows into total meltdown. I cannot even reinstall Windows.

HELP.

Comment: I am assuming that you have installed `hfsplus` in your Ubuntu.  If you have, maybe this might help:  https://askubuntu.com/a/676493/231142