# How do I find out where Ubuntu created partitions on my laptop?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have installed Ubuntu on my laptop and didn't choose manual partitioning during the installation. Now I'm not sure where exactly it created all Ubuntu -related partitions. I need to know so I can manage it later. I am dual- booting it alongside Windows 8.1. I am completely new to Linux.

Comment: How about trying `lsblk`?

Comment: Try `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I view all available HDD's/partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/182446/how-do-i-view-all-available-hdds-partitions)

Comment: @edwinksl 
Do I just write these in Terminal?

Comment: @Anto Yup, that's right.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [GParted](http://gparted.org/) for this; it will give you a nice graphical display of all partitions; you can also modify / delete / create partitions using it, if you want.

[image]

You can install it using the Software Center, or by typing `sudo apt-get install gparted`.

Comment: I installed it.. And one thing is bugging me.. I am supposed to select other drives in that button in upper right corner if available, right? Well as far as i see I can only select one.. Why is that?

Comment: @anto: That is the name of your harddisk. If you have multiple storage devices (internally or externally) they will show up there in a drop-down list. I mean any storage device: hdd, ssd, external hdd, USB stick, sd cards, even portables (phones, tablets, ebook readers), absolutely anything with storage capability whatsoever.

Comment: @ipse lute So even if I have 2 hdd-s in my laptop, it's all shown in that list?

Comment: @Anto Yes, it shows each hard drive separately. So you select your hard drive or storage device in that list, you can then see the partitions on it. If you only have one (i.e. the hard drive in your laptop), it will only show one. If you have a USB stick, or a second hard drive, you can select it in that list, yes.

Comment: @ipse lute well then i have  a problem.. I can't select other hdd..

Comment: If the other hdd is external try to unplug and reconnect it again. Is the other hdd recognized in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows , the equivalent of GParted is the Disk Management app. Just remember that Win doesn't recognize any linux partition. It will graphically show that space as unknown format. Make sure you don't (re)format that space, as it may belong to Ubuntu. You can read Ubuntu partitions from Win by using DiskInternals Linux Reader app. You can (only) read, but not write or modify linux partitions in any way from inside the Linux Reader.

Ubuntu has the upper hand, it can do read, write and modify both Win and linux partitions.

Comment: Thank you soo much i understand that little piece of Linux now :) BTW Do people usualy ask as many questions as I do haha because i kinda feel weird.. Asking so many questions haha Is there any way to talk to you guys from AskUbuntu via some kind of ChatRoom or?

Comment: @anto: Yes, there is chat room here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=askubuntu.com. You can ask as many questions as you like. There's no limit to that. Just make sure you are not creating duplicates or your own or of others. Search the site before asking anything. Other people may already found solutions for similar problems.

Comment: zthank you very much :) Ok, i'll check it out first