# How to inspect Ubuntu installed partition like inspecting windows installed (typically C:) partition?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, software-installation

I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu and trying to migrate from a windows environment. I recently set up my laptop to dual-boot Ubuntu with Windows. Since I have been used to Windows environment I always try to compare with Windows.

While setting up for dual booting, I created three new partitions, one for Ubuntu be installed (`/`), another one for home (`/home`) and the other one as the Linux-swap.

When I use the my laptop with Ubuntu I can see the `/home` partition and it's content when I browsed to *Home* in file in side bar. And other drives mounted in the bottom of the side bar. But how can I browse to the partition that I installed Ubuntu, like I go to the `C:` drive in windows. As per my understanding all the installed programs' files should be in this partition like `Program Files` in Windows. How can I see them?

I chose this Ubuntu installed partition to be `25 GB` as in some articles I found, they claimed around `20 GB` will be enough. How can I get to know if this is full. And can I choose `/home` or any other location for programs to be installed as we give a custom location in Windows?

I came across the question [How do I view all available HDD's/partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182446/how-do-i-view-all-available-hdds-partitions?newreg=2d05a48c48c04720b30a5bf650031096) and some related question to that, but those didn't really anwser my question.

Also please correct me if anything I have assumed above is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the Unity default file manager you can go to / by clicking Computer in the left pane. Or crtl-l and type it in. Posting as comment because I don't use Nautilus so details may be off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux the Program Files directory does not exist. The binaries or executables are placed in **/usr/bin/local, /bin, /opt**, or another directories defined in the **deb** package file. Moreover there are dependencies defined in the package, so the relevant libraries in your system are compatible with the new program binaries or executable file. If you are curious, you can download a deb package with

```
apt download deb_package_name
```

After downloading you can open it with Archiver - right click in Nautilus and open with choose Archiver. Double click on data.tar.xz and next double click on . , then you will see the directories, in which the program binaries will be placed.

Your C: drive is in Ubuntu the root file system / . On the root file system you can mount different partitions. The

```
sudo mount
```

command shows the currently mounted file systems.

With `man mount` command you can show in windows called help on particular command.

The file systems on your disk or the disks should be automatically shown in the Nautilus (default Ubuntu file browser). By clicking on the disk this is going to be mounted. If that succeeds, the disk drive will show the eject icon next to it. You can do the same with `sudo mount` or `sudo umount` commands. Be sure to specify your disk drive and the mount point:

```
sudo mkdir /media/newhd
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/newhd
```

where /dev/sdb1 is your first partition -1  on the second disk - sdb .

List of disks and partitions can be achieved with `lsblk` command.

Your **/home/user** directory can be compared to **c:\users\user_name** directory in Windows.

Comment: The `mount` command without parameters, i.e. to get the list of mounts, can be executed without `sudo`.

Comment: >And can I choose /home or any other location for programs to be installed as we give a custom location in Windows?

Comment: You can mout for instance a whole directory to point to a different drive. Look for fstab options when mounting at the boot time. Of course you can tweak the package to your needs or unpack it like here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242557/install-deb-package-files-in-another-directory

Comment: However I do not recommend this. After 5th package you will have pretty messy system.