# Problem with live iso run as installed

Tags: ext4, dd

There was an SSD drive with `Xubuntu` distro installed. If booted, I can see it has one `ext4` partition.

It worked fine but was planned to be moved to other HDD and to another machine.

I run live iso `Ubuntu 18.10`, started `GParted` and found out, that entire source drive is one partition of `iso9660` type. I didn't know how to handle this, so I cloned all the source drive using `dd`, and saved it as a file.

Now, when I write image to HDD, it does boot, but there are some errors in FS and it finishes in `initramfs`. But that's not the point.

I still have the exact image of original drive and my question is how can I get the inner OS from `iso9660` filesystem. After mounting this image I see and can browse only iso partition which is 2GB size. But where I can find target drive, `ext4` partition, mentioned before, that would be visible if I had booted from original drive?

**Update**

I ran a few tests and the results are not consistent. When using `fdisk` with `LiveISO`, it show `Linux` partition, when doing the same using `Gparted`, it shows `ISO9660`. Another test, booting `Ubuntu` from the subject, `fdisk` shows the same as before, `df -T` show `ext4`, but `Gparted` again - `iso9660`.

*LiveISO `fdisk`*
[image: LiveISO fdisk]

*LiveISO `GParted`*
[image: LiveISO GParted]

*Ubuntu `fdisk` and `df -T`*
[image]

*Ubuntu `GParted`*
[image]

Comment: Would you please open a terminal windows, run `sudo parted -l` , copy the results, come back here, click [edit] and paste those results into your question? Please do not use Add Comment as that loses for formatting and makes it very difficult to read and understand.

Comment: Did you remember to update GRUB after moving your Xubuntu install to a different drive/partition?

Comment: @K7AAY I can only run it in Live Ubuntu env as I don't have source drive and cloned HDD doesn't boot.

Comment: @user535733 no, I didn't update GRUB. I will do this from Live Ubuntu env

Comment: The ISO9660 partition is a clone of the ISO file, there is no new data on it. People generally want a full install of Ubuntu on the HDD as a Live install on the HDD is read only and will not save new programs or data. Better to use the 18.04 ISO file "Install Ubuntu" option to install to HDD.

Comment: Comment on your updated question: **I think that you can rely on the output from `fdisk` and `df`**. I know that `gparted` can get confused by some data near the head end of the drive, and I think this is what happened in this case. Maybe the physical sectors of the SSD and the HDD did not match, maybe some hardware driver did not match the hardware in the second computer, maybe there was some other cause for the failure to boot from the cloned copy (in the HDD).

Comment: @sudodus the same situation was on HDD before using SSD. Thanks, I will use CLI tools more often than before.

Comment: Also **`lsblk`** is reliable. It is easy to use `lsblk -f` and `lsblk -m`. See also [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182446/how-do-i-view-all-available-hdds-partitions/967730#967730). `parted` will often work, but suffers from the similar problems as `gparted`.

Answer (score 0):

### Installing ISO9660 File to HDD

The ISO9660 partition is a clone of the ISO file, Prior to 19.10 any space greater than the size of the ISO file is **wasted**. The Drive will fail if the ISO9660 partition is written to or modified.

A Live install on the HDD is **read only** and will not save new programs or data.

People generally want to put a full install of Ubuntu on the HDD, so that they can install programs and save data and settings. A full install also allows software updates and version upgrades, hibernation and proprietary drivers.

Use an app such as **UNetbootin** or **Rufus** to make an installer USB from your ISO file.

You can then use the Live USB "Install Ubuntu" option to install to HDD.

Another option is to dd your ext4 SSD install to another disk.

Comment: It was definitely a fully-operative OS, allowing to save data, files etc. Outside it looked like iso9660 when examining from Live Ubuntu, but after booting it was Xubuntu on ext4 partition. Drive's image is 180GB so I can't share it with You.

Comment: SSD is already in another aplication - can't use it. I did `dd` image to HDD and it does boot to `initramfs` - possibly only `GRUB update` needed. But after writing image to HDD, it still shows as `ISO9660`.

Comment: Can't install new OS, I need the one from my image. I can't afford loosing all the data and scripts. My situation does not fit to Your answer.

Comment: I did as You wrote: dd if=/source of=/image, but as I wrote before, writing this image to another drive (hdd) resulted in iso9660 fs, and not booting OS.

Comment: Some call dd disk destroyer, one small typo can make a lot of trouble. Is there any chance that you dd'd the ISO rather than the SSD?

Comment: Image has 180GB so possibility is realy low :-)

Comment: @qba-dev : If you use SDC or balenaEtcher to install Live 18.04 to SSD the ISO9660 partition will span the entire drive, but only ~2GB will have data on it. I think this can also be true for some dd.

Comment: I repaired FS and Grub, and it now runs fine, but still the mystery of iso9660 remains unraveled