finding which usb to pmount
pmount works from a command line to mount a USB drive (and unmount with pumount).  Pmount requires knowing which device and partition to mount.  If I plug in a thumb drive and if I'm on a GUI, I can use gnome-disks to determine if the specific thumb drive I'm wanting to mount is /dev/sdb1, /dev/sdc1 or perhaps /dev/sde1.  It will even confirm what the volume label name is - all without resorting to sudo.
How can I obtain similar information at a command line without resorting to sudo?   (device/partition)

This is a question and answer site. I see no question here.

@David DE Perhaps my editing makes the question standout now.  The question is how can I obtain similar information at a command line without resorting to sudo?

see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/333604/1698042

@Talaat Etman - every answer to the question you recommended requires sudo.  Perhaps I missed one?  The information is probably availabe because gnome-disks gets it without sudo somehow.

use this command without sudo: lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL

@Talaat Etman 's comment was close however, with all the LOOP stuff that would also cause many lines of results.  A shorter result, enough to feed a pmount command, would be
lsblk -o NAME,LABEL | grep sd

