# How to Assign Swap space for Ubuntu 12.04LTS?

Tags: 12.04, installation, swap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding swap partition after system installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/adding-swap-partition-after-system-installation)

I have total *4 drives*.

The primary one is of type ***ext3*** (ubuntu with 20GB free) and other 3 partitions are ***NTFS*** format/mount(with 20GB free)  installation.

I installed without swap space because i didn't know how to create it.

How can I assign swap space after installation without damaging my old data.
and can I use that swap space at emergency time?
Plz help me. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at this : [How to add a swap file](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/). By creating this swap file, you shouldn't damage your existing data

Comment: Please include details from the link. The community frowns upon link-only answers.