# How to edit partition table in Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS?

Tags: partitioning, swap

When installing, I used the advanced setup and I do not recall whether or not I added a swap partition. Upon boot I typically have to wait for "cryptswap1" to be ready. It does work, but I usually skip with the "s" key. Upon this boot, I skipped waiting and proceeded to do some work. Currently, I am attempting to install a package from the Ubuntu Software Center named (I think it's called 'hibernate' or 'Smartly', something like that). It requires a swap space, and claims to detect none.
If I open the disk utility, this is what I see:

[image]

Anyway, I should get to my point. Just wanted to make sure I have as much information as possible if something is important.

Basically, if I have no swap partition, can I decrease the size of some partitions to add a new swap partition? If so, how? And which partitions should I decrease? I have about 2 GB of RAM, but when I had Windows 7 on here when I got the laptop, it said only 1.86 or so was usable. If I had created a swap partition, knowing me I would make it twice the ram plus an extra GB 'just in case'. I know it wouldn't be used. I think this may be what the 5GB unknown partition is, but it says unknown rather than swap, and it also says "Master Boot Sector" as the format. Tell me if I'm right or wrong on this.

If I do have a swap partition, why wasn't it detected by the software? Is it because I skipped waiting? If this is correct, would rebooting and waiting fix this?

I would IMMENSELY appreciate any help in this issue.

I am new to "Ask Ubuntu", so I don't know if I will receive an email for any replies. Hopefully I will get some sort of email, but if not I should be checking this every once in a while.

Again, thanks for any help on this. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. No, it is not a forum. See this short introduction how thing works here [About].

Comment: Open Terminal Ctrl+Alt+t , run `sudo fdisk -l` , then add its outputs the question. (It will be very helpful)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a full list of you partitions then you can use

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
```

and see this solution for adding a SWAP partition

[How do I add a swap partition after system installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-a-swap-partition-after-system-installation)