# How to create swap file on ext4

Tags: partitioning, mount, 14.04, fstab, swap

My friend whats to create a 4GB swap file on his ext4 file system. because he is using a chromebook acer c7 the way he installed he did not have a chance to specify swap partition

and now he want to create a swap file on his file system.

This is the guide he is following

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1618220&p=10098565#post10098565

First you have to create a 2GiB file, for example in /mnt:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/swap bs=1M count=2048
```

Then format the file to swap:

```
sudo mkswap /mnt/swap
```

Add the swap file to the system:

```
sudo swapon /mnt/swap
```

Check it out, i.e.:

```
free -m
```

Edit the fstab file:

```
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

and add this line at the end of the file:

```
/mnt/swap  none  swap  sw
```

Save the file and exit. That's all.

**This is what he is getting**

[image]

```
user@chrubuntu:~$ sudo swapon /mnt/swap
swapon: /mnt/swap: swapon failed: Invalid argument
```

**and his fstab looks like this**

[image: fstab]

any way to fix this ??

One more thing he is using ubuntu 14.04 and it is not a fresh install

Thank you for your time

Comment: Does he get the error you've mentioned both times he tries to run `swapon`, or just after he's added it to the fstab file?

Comment: @Levan the fstab file doesn't have the /mnt/swap  none  swap  sw at the end of the file. Save the file after editing.

Comment: Thank you for the reply he follows the above guide that i mantioned

before this step every thing works Add the swap file to the system:

sudo swapon /mnt/swap

http://imgur.com/rFP0gbc

Comment: Is this system running a custom kernel?  What does `uname -a` show?

Comment: @psusi Thank you for the reply again this is what it say `ser@chrubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux chrubuntu 3.4.0 #1 SMP Fri Apr 11 19:07:10 PDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
user@chrubuntu:~$`

Comment: @psusi I have a question, what do you think if he manually upgrades to the latest kernel?? will his chrome book still boot or it is too dangerous

Comment: I don't know enough about it, but it certainly appears to have a custom, older, kernel, but if you check its config file in /boot, you may find that it was built without CONFIG_SWAP, so doesn't support swap.

Comment: @psusi thank you you have been tremendous help, crazy thing is that he can not even upgrade to a newer kernel

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the problem is because it's in the /mnt directory or it could be a security issue world readable swap isn't great. Try this tutorial and see if you have better results.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/

Comment: Thank you for the reply I will tell him and notify you about the result

Comment: Small preamble this is the  **UUID=c8a5817e-90d3-48f3-976a-8e80de5e6a4b** he got this is the command he used `sudo swapon -U c8a5817e-90d3-48f3-976a-8e80de5e6a4b` and sadly this is what terminal told **him swapon cannot find the device**

Comment: @Levan please provide the output of ls -a /mnt

Comment: @Levan please provide the output of the command       ls -a /mnt   we are missing the ls

Comment: sorry @Elder Geek  small mix up this is what he got `user@chrubuntu:~$ ls -a /mnt
.  ..  swap
user@chrubuntu:~$`  I do not understand did not the terminal say that it created a file ??

Comment: That's definitely not going to work; uuid recognition only works on partitions, not files.

Comment: @psusi any suggestions ??? and thank you fore the reply

Comment: @Levan just double-checking

Comment: @Elder Geek thank you very much for the help/time/afford

Answer (score 0):

> swapon failed: Invalid argument

Based on this [discussion](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/linux-btrfs/2009/1/20/4775284) and this [post](https://superuser.com/a/539875/87805), most likely your file system doesn't support swap files.

You need to create it somewhere outside of `/mnt`, as part of the native filesystem (e.g. in `/var`).

Try following [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/796997/78223) instead.