# Hibernation/swap partition

Tags: partitioning, swap, hibernate

I'm trying to enable hibernation on my laptop, a Dell XPS-13 (with a 256 GB SSD mounted as an encrypted volume).

I was following the official documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html) and I attempted the "hibernation test" by executing `sudo pm-hibernate` from a command prompt. Needless to say it failed, in the sense that the screen went dark for a few seconds and then everything resumed as-was. The documentation mentioned checking whether the swap partition in "at least as large as available RAM" (in my case, 8 GB).

So I typed `df` and this is what I saw (I've made extensive use of tmps in my `/etc/fstab` to avoid needless grind on the SSD):

```
user@host:~$ df
Filesystem                  1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 237978256 14144120 211722472   7% /
none                                4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                          3829132        4   3829128   1% /dev
tmpfs                         3844736     2060   3842676   1% /tmp
tmpfs                          768948     1324    767624   1% /run
none                             5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                          3844736    32312   3812424   1% /run/shm
none                           102400       28    102372   1% /run/user    
tmpfs                         3844736        0   3844736   0% /var/spool
tmpfs                         3844736       24   3844712   1% /var/tmp
tmpfs                         3844736      936   3843800   1% /var/log
/dev/sda1                      240972    84550    143981  37% /boot
/home/user/.Private        237978256 14144120 211722472   7%  /home/user
user@host:~$
```

Am I right in my diagnosis that I have no swap partition at all??

(I have `vm.swappiness` set to 0, if I remember correctly, in case that's relevant in any way.)

If I'm right in my diagnosis, how do I go about creating one at this late moment in time?

Answer (score 3):

Searching the internet helped me discover that `sudo swapon -s` will report whether a swapfile is active or not, and if so, where it is. It turns out that as I suspected I don't have one active, which is pretty surprising but explains a lot of things.

Now I will follow [the procedure indicated here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04) to enable one.

Comment: As a general rule, do web searches before you post on the forum :).

Comment: You won't be able to hibernate with a swap **file**. You will need a swap partition. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-a-swap-partition-after-system-installation on how to create one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Indeed I was wondering whether I could get off easily by creating myself a swapfile, but you pre-empted that. The dilemma I'm facing now is whether to create the swap partition within the LUKS volume or alongside it.