# I need help in creating swap after installation 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, swap

I installed Ubuntu and forgot to create swap during installation... So I did cut off 4GiB out of my system partition and I'm confused what to do next? I can reboot Ubuntu everything is fine but when I run:

```
sudo blkid
```

or

```
sudo parted -l
```

or

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

it doesn't appear anywhere... for example this output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA Hitachi HDP72503 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
1      32,3kB  47,5GB  47,5GB  primary   ext4         boot
3     47,5GB  51,5GB  3999MB  primary   linux-swap(v1)
2      51,5GB  320GB   269GB   extended
5      51,5GB  320GB   269GB   logical   ntfs


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).
/dev/sr0 has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
```

I was using this [topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-a-swap-partition-after-system-installation) but still cannot figure it out.

other outputs:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x27252724

/dev/sda1   *          63    92851625    46425781+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2       100663357   625137344   262236994    5  Расширенный
/dev/sda3        92852224   100663295     3905536   82  Linux своп / Solaris
/dev/sda5       100663359   625137344   262236993    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

and:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="98b0cee6-3b81-4e39-bb43-4847e297b7ff" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="807aba97-139f-4170-9bbf-5b58def95125" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="2644E68F76515A43" TYPE="ntfs"
```

and:

```
free -l
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
memory:    2063796    1238992     824804       8024      78256     535504
Low:        880428     576176     304252
High:      1183368     662816     520552
-/+ buffer/cache:     625232    1438564
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Comment: please edit the question with the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo blkid`

Comment: I did the outputs.

Comment: there's no 4GB partition visible in the outputs. what did you do to create the 4GB partition? please post the output of `df -h`

Comment: I appologize please take a look at my re-edited post. How do I ensure if everything is ok?

Comment: the `free -l` command gives the status of RAM . we don't want that. post the output of `df -h` which will give the filesystem disk space usage for all mounted partitions

Comment: thank you for the help but I figured it out already I edited `fstab` with an appropriate swap `UUID` and it seems ok now even in `Gparted` it says activated.

Comment: I suspect you only freed up some space on you disk but didn't create a new partition with it. Unfortunately `parted` and `fdisk` don't display unallocated space very obviously. Can you make a screen shot with GParted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin, one last check to make sure you definitely don't have swap:

```
sudo swapon -s
```

This should list any available swap files. If nothing is listed then you will need to create one. The following command will create a 4gb swap, as an approximate rule the size of your swap should be the same size as the amount of RAM your machine has:

```
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
```

(obviously replace 4G with 8G if you have 8gb of RAM etc.!)

Verify that the swap size is correct with:

```
ls -lh /swapfile
```

Next set the permissions on the swap file so it's only accessible by root:

```
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
```

Next set the swap file up using:

```
sudo mkswap /swapfile
```

Finally use the following command to enable the swap:

```
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

You can check that swap is now in use by typing:

```
sudo swapon -s
```

Congrats, you should now have swap. Next you might want to...

**Make swap automatically load at startup:**

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

And then add the following line to the bottom of the file:

```
/swapfile   none    swap    sw    0   0
```

For more information, such as optimizing swap, [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04) has a great overview.

Comment: when I run `sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile` it says 
`fallocate: /swapfile: fallocate failed: No space left on device`

Comment: you can try `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096` instead of `sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile`.

Comment: I re-edited my question if you can take a look now when I run `sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile` nothing appears

Comment: thank you I figured it out with the help of your answer. It seems ok now.

Comment: Swap files have the distinct disadvantage of being incompatible with suspension to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Many OS' allow the option for dynamic paging files, which grow and shrink depending on need. Most linuxes, including ubuntu, do not, I think, allow this option by default.

I use the fantastic program swapspace for managing dynamic paging files, available with more information from here: http://pqxx.org/development/swapspace/ I generally find this is the simplest way of managing swap on ubuntu.