# Allocate swap after Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation

Tags: 14.04, swap

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS about one month ago, I'm dual booting Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Windows 8.1.

I didn't create any swap space while installation but now I really need to add this for Ubunutu. I tried checking for any assigned swap space by using `sudo swapon -s` and I got empty headers like shown below:

```
ahsan@ahsan-Inspiron-N5110:~$ sudo swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
```

Then I tried to allocate some swap space using `dd of=output.dat bs=1 seek=390143672 count=0` and the output was:

```
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.000170607 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

I also tried the command `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=4` and output was:

```
dd: memory exhausted by input buffer of size 1073741824 bytes (1.0 GiB)
```

Then I tried `sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile` but output was:

```
fallocate: /swapfile: fallocate failed: Operation not supported
```

I aslo checked my hard drives following is my hard drive structure:

```
ahsan@ahsan-Inspiron-N5110:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        99G   18G   77G  19% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.4G  4.0K  1.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           286M  1.2M  284M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.4G   24M  1.4G   2% /run/shm
none            100M   56K  100M   1% /run/user
```

And the output of `free -m` is:

```
ahsan@ahsan-Inspiron-N5110:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2850       2665        184        421         25        846
-/+ buffers/cache:       1794       1055
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Please show me how can I add the swap without affecting any data of mine. I've installed 64 bit Ubuntu LTS and have 3GB of RAM and a 500GB hard drive.

I have been to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/549201/371765) Ask Ubuntu question and I tried the commands and the output is:

```
ahsan@ahsan-Inspiron-N5110:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapspace bs=1G count=4
4+0 records in
4+0 records out
4294967296 bytes (4.3 GB) copied, 47.1951 s, 91.0 MB/s
ahsan@ahsan-Inspiron-N5110:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapspace bs=1G count=4sudo mkswap /swapspace
dd: invalid number ‘4sudo’
ahsan@ahsan-Inspiron-N5110:~$
```

Comment: Exactly what you want to fix? "memory exhausted by input buffer", fallocate?

Comment: The clue was in the error message `dd: invalid number '4sudo'`, right? I would guess you had a copy/paste problem. Glad you got your problem solved! In the future, read those error messages carefully and try to figure out why you're getting that message!;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

First, to create 4,000 MB of swap space:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapspace bs=1M count=4000
4000+0 records in
4000+0 records out
4194304000 bytes (4.2 GB) copied, 5.92647 s, 708 MB/s
```

*or*

```
$ sudo fallocate -l 4000M /swapspace
```

Next turn it into a usable swap file:

```
$ sudo mkswap /swapspace
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 4095996 KiB
no label, UUID=7d1895e4-7ccf-42c6-979a-51ebddb49e91
```

Activate it:

```
$ sudo swapon /swapspace
```

Confirm active swap spaces:

```
$ cat /proc/swaps
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapspace              file        4095996 0       -1
```

Next, add the following line to /etc/fstab to activate the new swap at boot:

```
/swapspace none swap defaults 0 0
```

See also this wiki page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Comment: edited the question can you please have a look

Comment: sorry i mistakenly tried to run command twice, i think its worked for me :) now also showing swap in system monitor.. Thanks alot

Comment: i restarted the machine and the swap is gone, its again not available

Comment: The "running out of memory" part should be added to the answer. Comments are meant to be transient, they may be deleted.

Comment: _sudo apt-get install swapspace_  is best option compare to allocating like this?

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question indirectly, you don't need to manage swapfiles yourself. There is a package called swapspace which will dynamically add swap files as needed.

1. sudo apt-get install swapspace

Then you are done. Your system will grow and shrink swap space as needed.

Answer (score 5):

Follow these steps:

1. `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/{filename}.swap bs=1M count={swap_size}`
2. `sudo mkswap /mnt/{filename}.swap`
3. `sudo swapon /mnt/{filename}.swap`
4. `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`
5. Add the following text at the end of the file, `/mnt/{filename}.swap  none  swap  sw  0 0`

Note: Replace {filename} with any name you want to set to the file and replace {swap_size} with the size you want to assign to the swap file. Be sure the size of the file must the twice larger than the memory size.

Comment: *"Be sure the size of the file must the twice larger than the memory size."* That advice no longer holds nowadays unless you're really low on memory (say, 1 GB or less). If you want to use hibernation, you'll need at least the amount of physical memory as swap, but there's no reason to have 8 GB swap if you have 4 GB RAM.

Comment: Your suggestion is considered.