# How to use swapspace application?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, swap

I have installed swapspace a few weeks back. I have followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/570987/158636) for installing swapspace in my ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install swapspace
#confirmed installation using "man swapspace"
```

I have used this application because it will dynamically make a swap space  as per the system requirement and also I find the manual creation of swap space daunting.

But after a fresh reboot when I tried to find my swap space using these commands

```
$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority

$ free -m
Swap:            0          0          0
```

shows no swap space in my system?

How should I use swapspace?

Comment: First of all, did you partition your drive with a swap partition when you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: To find out, run `fdisk -l` and give us the output.

Comment: I think I didnt used a swap partition while installing ubuntu. Its  a long time ago so I am not sure. `fdisk  -l ` it outputs nothing. Do we need a separate partition for swap space. I read that we can create swap file with out a separate partition

Comment: Can you give the output of `fdisk -l`?

Comment: It will show whether or not you did

Comment: I have no swap partition, only static  /swap.img file in root, tried `sudo systemctl start swapspace.service` but no new swap files are created when entire memory is consumed, even if i swapoff static one before starting swapspace service. Debian9.

Comment: Their readme file has the installation procedure: https://github.com/Tookmund/Swapspace/blob/master/README.md