# How to use SwapSpace program

Tags: swap, 19.04

I would like to use a dynamically expanding swap file, I install swapspace to do this

```
sudo apt-get install swapspace
```

Then I configured `/etc/swapspace.conf`

I have a 10MiB swap file already in `/var/swapfile` 
However, nothing seems to be working. In top and system monitor the amount of swap space is not changing

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you start or check status of service with `sudo systemctl start swapspace.service`?

Comment: I have similar problem, started service, consumed memory with `stress-ng` but no new swap images are added. I get only memory allocation errors.

Comment: The readme file of swapspace mentions the procedure: https://github.com/Tookmund/Swapspace/blob/master/README.md