# How do I save modification to Linux Swap Size?

Tags: swap

I have Linux device at my school and I increased swap size from **1983** to **3007** using `swapon`. However the modifications are not saved and are lost upon rebooting. How do I save these?

Comment: Do you mean Linux's `swap` memory?

Comment: What does "I must go from 1983 to 3007" mean? Are you attempting time travel? How exactly did you do that? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Take a look to [this (possible duplicate) answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/33697/349837).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean edit the size of swap from count=1983 towards 3007.

**First, swap location:**
To discover your swap location, use the command `swapon -s`. In my case:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-1               partition   2097148 0       -1
```

**Turn swap off:**
Before we can edit our swap file, we have to turn it off. Logical, cause it is in 'use'. You can check how much swap is used by the command `free -m`.

Here you can read about memory usage, [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/85470/meaning-of-the-buffers-cache-line-in-the-output-of-free).

Command to turn swap off:
`sudo swapoff -a`

**Edit swap size:**
Now we are able to edit the size, we do that by the command `dd`.

> *Be carefull with commands like these, I advice you to read the manual before blind copying my command.*

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/dm-1 bs=1M count=3007`

**Initialize swap:**
mkswap sets up a Linux swap area on a device or in a file.
`sudo mkswap /dev/dm-1`

Final, turn swap on:
`sudo swapon /dev/dm-1`

**Please educate yourself and don't just try to complete an assignment without understanding how it works.**

Answer (score -1):

First, you can do it with Gparted (right clicked the partition & selected "swapon").

If you need to install gparted first : `apt-get install gparted -y`

Otherwise, you  have to configure the swap partition in **/etc/fstab** to get it mounted automatically on boot. Same as with any other partitions you'd want mounted on boot.

Check the correct UUID for the partition using sudo **blkid** command, and then add a line like this in fstab (with the correct UUID):

```
UUID=d228f3a3-585c-447e-aab4-91a3d089e193 none swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: What problem are you addressing to?