# Weird sda3 partition - did Ubuntu intentionally reserve space on SSD drive?

Tags: 14.04, ssd, gparted

I see weird ~15 Gb of unused space on my 512 Gb SSD drive:

[image]

I'm pretty sure that during installation I choose "use entire disk and don't bother me with stupid questions" option. I didn't create a swap partition, besides I think it would be marked as swap in this case. Could it be some sort of recovery partition left from previous Windows installation?

Or Ubuntu just reserved some disk space to prolong SSD live? I just run smartctl and so far disk looks quite healthy - no relocations in two years http://afiskon.ru/s/8c/bfd409af71_smart.txt

Does anyone have an idea what is sda3 for? Is it safe to delete sda3 and enlarge sda2 partition?

Comment: No idea why it failed to get partitioned but it appears that unless you have a swap on another partition your /sda3 should have been partitioned as /swap. You can still add this [this space as /swap partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-a-swap-partition-after-system-installation).

Comment: This is strange. The fact that it's a partition is weird. Normally, if unused by the installation, this space should be simply "unallocated". Which shouldn't happen anyhow in your scenario. I'd look for some installation logs or try to reinstall and look at the installation messages.

Comment: When you encrypt /home, swap is also encrypted. And then gparted and other tools cannot see partition.

Answer (score 0):

Well I checked /etc/fstab:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda3
#UUID=b04d45f1-b892-4700-8f68-f1ad1ca21fbf none  swap sw 0 0
#/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

Turned out it **was** a swap partition. I solved all my problems using Ubuntu bootable USB stick and gparted.