# My Ubuntu 16.04 system hangs

Tags: 16.04, swap, system

I can not move the mouse and use the keyboard, it seems that either the processor to become loaded onto the 100% or the operating memory (perhaps some memory leak). Unfortunately I can not even switch to htop that to see what was happening. Everything happens at lightning speed and either rapidly or over time within a minute

What started:
1. Chromium Google Chrome, or (1 to 4 tabs, one of them on YouTube video or audio).
2. Android Studio.
3. Terminal Guake
4. Terminal Terminator
No more no cumbersome processes or tasks is not super.
The last time the computer hangs when I decided to do a simple code (such as Hello WORLD) in Android Studio.

Similar problems I had on Arch Linux on the same hardware. When I start Steam and tried to play DotA or other games.

Hardware: Amd phenom 4 core, 4 gb ddr2, nvidia 650ti.

My question is: What i need to do?  How to find and identify a problem, how to get rid of it

My logs:
[Dmesg](http://pastebin.com/pYWcZdGf) , [syslog](http://pastebin.com/NQEC5bsq)

BTW: i dont have SWAP partion, maybe problem in this?

Comment: Does this problem emerged after any update or software/hardware change ? Till your problem is not solved, you can go through this http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes

Comment: Hello! Nope, i have frash  install ubuntu and didnt any update (dont love them =). Btw - i added swap in my system and cant recreate a problem.

Comment: What does "can't recreate a problem" means ?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, i mean repeat this problem again.

Comment: Please take your time and restructure your question.

Comment: Please be specific in what you did and the current status, till then you can visit the link mentioned above.

Comment: @george my question is ideal, how to find problem from wich my system hangs on. As i say i dont have SWAP partition, i added 16 gb swap, and cant repeat this problem again.  So i think  i dont need here help again.

Answer (score 0):

My system was without SWAP partition, so i installed SWAP 16Gb, by this  [Takkat answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-a-swap-partition-after-system-installation) , and now all works fine and no fully hangs on with many running applications.