# 16.04 LTS hard crashes

Tags: crash, memory-usage

I installed Ubuntu for the first time yesterday and am working with it now and was happy, until it crashed, twice, in 4 hours of work. Crash=no mouse, no keyboard, no life.
I ran the command, both times: alt-prt scr and wrote REISUB. It reboots. I want to find out why it crashes, and fix it. I have intel integrated graphics.
I don't believe it is a hardware problem because Windows work fine on this hardware. All help appreciated.

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /var/log/syslog` at http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Ok, I did it, under my name.

Comment: Can you post the link?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24270410/

Comment: I really love Ubuntu. But freezing twice a day is not something I can live with. Anyone has encountered this and can help? @AndroidDev, have you found any pointers to give me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56259/discussion-between-hugues-rousseau-and-android-dev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that the OP's computer ran out of RAM, as evidenced by these lines from the syslog:

```
Mar 28 15:43:50 hugues-HP-ProBook-4530s kernel: [ 5020.228198] Out of memory: Kill process 25673 (node) score 426 or sacrifice child
Mar 28 15:43:50 hugues-HP-ProBook-4530s kernel: [ 5020.228234] Killed process 25673 (node) total-vm:1714884kB, anon-rss:501900kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Mar 28 15:43:50 hugues-HP-ProBook-4530s kernel: [ 5020.264947] oom_reaper: reaped process 25673 (node), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Mar 28 15:43:57 hugues-HP-ProBook-4530s kernel: [ 5028.658675] sysrq: SysRq : HELP : loglevel(0-9) reboot(b) crash(c) terminate-all-tasks(e) memory-full-oom-kill(f) kill-all-tasks(i) thaw-filesystems(j) sak(k) show-backtrace-all-active-cpus(l) show-memory-usage(m) nice-all-RT-tasks(n) poweroff(o) show-registers(p) show-all-timers(q) unraw(r) sync(s) show-task-states(t) unmount(u) force-fb(V) show-blocked-tasks(w) dump-ftrace-buffer(z) 
Mar 28 15:43:58 hugues-HP-ProBook-4530s kernel: [ 5029.400548] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
Mar 28 15:43:58 hugues-HP-ProBook-4530s kernel: [ 5029.752964] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
Mar 28 15:43:59 hugues-HP-ProBook-4530s kernel: [ 5030.203206] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
Mar 28 15:43:59 hugues-HP-ProBook-4530s kernel: [ 5030.733980] sysrq: SysRq : Emergency Sync
```

In the chat, the OP said he only has 4GB of RAM and disabled swap, so running out of memory was definitely the issue.

---

The only fix here is to [buy some more RAM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007B5S52C).

Comment: I agree with Android Dev that your laptop needs more RAM, but if you don't want to buy more RAM for your HP ProBook 4530s or if you have difficulty finding RAM that is compatible with your laptop, an alternative solution is to add a 6GB or 8GB swap partition. You can add a swap partition by following the instructions in the answers to [How do I add a swap partition after system installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-a-swap-partition-after-system-installation).

Comment: @karel - True, but 1) His laptop uses DDR3-1600 which is cheap and easy to find and 2) he was running programs that take a lot of RAM, so it would slow to a crawl if he used swap