# Ubuntu 16.04 boots slow

Tags: boot, systemd

I found that I had an entry for swap space in /etc/fstab but I didn't have any swap space in my PC , that created issue.

But, I was unable to understand the same from systemd-analyze plot, can someone tell me which service takes more time because of additional entry in fstab from below shared plot.

[systemd plot of my pc ubuntu 16.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VadFd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Missing swap that is referenced in /etc/fstab will slow your boot down.
Either remove the line for the swap in /etc/fstab, or create swap and update the swap line in /etc/fstab.

take a look at:

[How do I add a swap partition after system installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-a-swap-partition-after-system-installation)

Comment: I have identified and removed it . But, My question was how can I identify the same from systemd-analyze that I have attached ?