# Swap: From partition to file, now get "no matching swap device is available"

Tags: swap, resume, uuid

Running Ubuntu 18.04, I changed from a swap partition to a swap file.

`swapon -s` (summary) and free show the swapfile with the new size.  /etc/fstab was changed, permission on the swapfile changed and the swap partition was deleted. When there are updates (apt-get update and upgrade), I get this error:

> ```
> Setting up amd64-microcode (3.20180524.1~ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
> update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
> amd64-microcode: microcode will be updated at next boot
> Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
> Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.1) ...
> update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
> W: initramfs-tools configuration sets RESUME=UUID=c5a2c6f4-b67c-4d95-bc23-8333ed6c0f11
> W: but no matching swap device is available.
> ```

The UUID listed there is for the old swap partition. I didn't think a swap file has a UUID, but I am not sure about that.  Everything else seems to work fine. How should I proceed to troubleshoot and fix this?

Comment: What does this show? `sudo swapon --show`?  And: `ls -lh /swapfile`

Comment: outputs are:
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file   3G   0B   -2
and 
-rw------- 1 root root 3.0G Jul 10 13:00 /swapfile

Comment: Those look essentially the same as mine. What does fstab show? Post above to preserve formatting. `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: Tried to post it above, but text was huge.  Just going to put the last lines (about swap) here:
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
#UUID=c5a2c6f4-b67c-4d95-bc23-8333ed6c0f11 none            swap    #sw              0       0
# swap now in /swapfile
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0

Comment: It's not an error, `W:` stands for `Warning`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That line is in /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume  so try deleting it.

---

The file in question, /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume, hasn't
even existed in an Ubuntu LTS release since 14.04. Deleting the
one line it contained on an 18.04 system will never cause a problem.
This is a great example of why a reinstall is preferable to an upgrade,
sometimes old things get left which can later cause problems.

As for those who think blkid will produce anything at all for
a swapfile, you are wrong, and the answer which suggest using
blkid is non-responsive to the stated problem.  Reread the question,
there is no longer a swap partition.

As a comment suggested, a UUID for the swapfile may be produced with
swaplabel, but it is left as an exercise for the reader to see if using
that swapfile UUID in a configuration file which is no longer part of the
Ubuntu system will actually fix anything, or just result in another
UUID lookup failure.

Comment: +1 Yes. Delete it or replace with `RESUME=NONE` or make it a comment (put a **`#`** in the beginning of the line).

Comment: Deleted it, reboot, reran apt update and upgrade. initramfs updated with no errors.  Thanks!

Comment: `RESUME=NONE` does not work on Ubuntu LTS 18.04. **Deleting the line** or `RESUME=` does work.

Comment: this screws up new debian and ubuntu installs. the answer below fixes it properly... just do that.

Comment: This answer is terrible advice. Please don't just delete stuff from Linux that you don't understand. How this is the accepted answer is baffling. Instead, follow the instruction in the other answers on using `blkid` to determine the correct swap partition UUID and substitute that!

Comment: This answer is also not fully correct, first I had this file on Ubuntu 16.04 which was the first installed version and on another instance on ubuntu 20.04 I had this error without having this file and adding it with the blkid fixed the issue

Comment: @dovetalk: Your comment is terrible advice. You haven't even read the question. There is no more swap partition so using `blkid` to find its UUID is not applicable.

Comment: It seems you did not read the other (higher voted) answer, which shows how to find the active UUID and replace the inactive with that. Not to use if to find the deleted one. But OK.

Answer (score 45):

Step 1:

```
$ sudo blkid
```

It will list get UUID of each device or partition on your system. Copy the UUID of swap partition.

Step 2:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

Replace the available UUID with paste the UUID which you just copied and save it.

Step 3:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: 'sudo swaplabel /swapfile' will actually show the UUID of swap **FILE**. `sudo blkid` shows partitions, not `/swapfile`. At least it is so in my case. Do you have a `/swapfile` created?

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. I hate those lazy "Delete it" answers.

Comment: This answer is invalid for this case. The OP stated: "The UUID listed there is for the old swap partition. I didn't think a swap file has a UUID". He is right. If he does not use a swap partition anymore, but a swap file, then there is no more UUID to deal with. So, this answer is out of purpose for this case. But, it can be useful for those that use a swap partition...

Comment: This is an incorrect answer for distros that have moved to using a swapfile.

Answer (score -3):

Editing /etc/fstab with new UUID of swap worked fine boot time reduced to 10 seconds from 2 mins

Comment: Perfect, but how is this related to `no matching swap device available`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem, which is the RESUME swap partition in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`. Not `/etc/fstab`!