# Hibernate or suspend not working on Xubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, suspend, hibernate, dell-vostro

Recently installed Xubuntu 18.04 LTS(bionic beaver) as dual boot alongside Windows 10 on my Dell laptop. Neither hibernation nor suspend is working. When I close the lid of my computer and open it again I get a black screen. Machine seems to be running but I get no response. Only option is to hit the shutdown button to force shutdown.

Since I did not create a swap partition on installation, I used a live cd to resize my Ubuntu partition and create a swap partition. I also hit the *swapon* option in Gparted.

Rebooted the computer back into Xubntu but still no go... same problem with suspend and hibernate.

I've looked at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/33703/975225) to edit `/etc/fstab` but I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do.

here's how my`/etc/stab` file looks like:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation 
UUID=7adff708-01f9-4897-92e9-647aae470f4f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=3E4C-F177  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1 /swapfile            none            swap    sw              0       0
```

laptop specs:

- bus            Motherboard
- memory         7874MiB
- processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
- bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
- display        HD Graphics 620
- generic        Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
- bus            Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
- generic        Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem

Comment: Hibernate by definition means requires the power to be turned off, so any memory contents will be lost - and swap is where those contents go.  For hibernate to work you must have sufficient swap to save whatever is already in swap + the full contents of your ram.  You didn't tell us what release of Xubuntu (thus we don't know if you can use swap files, or swap only).  Rather than forcing shutdown (which will force a `fsck`) do sysrq keys allow shutdown? Also please don't include pictures of text (harder to read & we can't copy/paste from them).

Comment: added xubuntu version. I tried sysrq keys for restart and it worked. @guiverc